# Is there a 'catch' with FastFormat?

Tags: c++, fastformat

I just read about the [FastFormat C++ i/o formatting library](http://www.fastformat.org/), and it seems too good to be true: Faster even than printf, typesafe, and with what I consider a pleasing interface:

```
// prints: "This formats the remaining arguments based on their order - in this case we put 1 before zero, followed by 1 again"
fastformat::fmt(std::cout, "This formats the remaining arguments based on their order - in this case we put {1} before {0}, followed by {1} again", "zero", 1);

// prints: "This writes each argument in the order, so first zero followed by 1"
fastformat::write(std::cout, "This writes each argument in the order, so first ", "zero", " followed by ", 1);
```

This looks almost too good to be true. Is there a catch? Have you had good, bad or indifferent experiences with it?

Comment: How does it know how to write arbitrary objects in the `write()` case?  For that matter, how does it know when it hit the end of the argument list?  Is it not using `<stdarg.h>`?

Comment: An interesting performance is to measure this library versus a `sprintf` and `fwrite` pair.  The second fastest method to output formatted data is to format to memory then block write to the output.  *The fastest method is not to use formatted output.*

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a 'catch' with FastFormat?

Last time I checked, there was one annoying catch:

You can only use *either* the narrow string version *or* the wide string version of this library. (The functions for `wchar_t` and `char` are the same -- which type is used is a compile time switch.)

With iostreams, stdio or Boost.Format you can use both.

Answer (score 5):

Found one "catch", though for most people it will *never* manifest.  From the project page:

> **Atomic operation.**  It doesn't write out statement elements one at a time, like the IOStreams, so has no atomicity issues

The only way I can see this happening is if it buffers the whole `write()` call's output itself, then writes it out to the `ostream` in one step.  This means it needs to allocate memory, and if an object passed into the `write()` call produces a lot of output (several megabytes or more), it can consume up to twice that much memory in internal buffers (assuming it uses the grow-a-buffer-by-doubling-its-size-each-time trick).

If you're just using it for logging, and not, say, dumping huge amounts of XML, you'll never see this problem.

The only other "catch" I'm seeing is:

> **Highly portable.** It will work with all good modern C++ compilers; it even works with Visual C++ 6!

So it won't work with an old C++ compiler, like `cfront`, whereas `iostreams` is backward compatible to the late 80's.  Again, I'd be surprised if anyone ever had a problem with this.

Comment: The memory allocation can indeed be an issue on embedded systems.

Comment: True that.  I'm working on gettin FreeRTOS up and running on a Cortex-M3 chip.  They provide two memory allocators you can use instead of `malloc()`/`free()` because those routines are (relatively) big, slow, and overkill in most embedded apps.

Comment: It also does not support MSVC 2012

Comment: Well, this *was* 2009. Anyway, if it works with MSVC++ 6, there should be a way to port it. (Now if you're saying it doesn't work with **C**, well, can't help you there...)

Answer (score 4):

Although FastFormat is a good library there are a number of issues with it:

- Limited formatting support, in particular the following features are not supported:

  - Leading zeros (or any other non-space padding)
  - Octal/hexadecimal encoding
  - Runtime width/alignment specification
- The library is quite big for a relatively small task of formatting and has even bigger dependency (STLSoft).

Answer (score 2):

It looks pretty interesting indeed! Good tip regardless, and +1 for that!

I've been playing with it for a bit. The main drawback I see is that FastFormat supports less formatting options for the output. This is I think a direct consequence of the way the higher typesafety is achieved, and a good tradeoff depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in detail at his performance benchmark page, you'll notice that good old C `printf`-family functions are still winning on Linux.  In fact, the only test case where they perform poorly is the test case that should be static string concatenations, where I would expect `printf` to be wasteful.  Moreover, GCC provides static type-checking on `printf`-style function calls, so the benefit of type-safety is reduced.  So:  *if* you are running on Linux and *if* you need the absolute best performance, FastFormat is probably not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The library depends on a couple of environment variables, as mentioned in [the docs](http://www.fastformat.org/documentation/index.html).

That might be no biggie to some people, but I'd prefer my code to be as self-contained as possible. If I check it out from source control, it should work and compile. It won't, if it requires you to set environment variables.

Comment: That answer confused me at first! :-) You need some environment variables to get it to build, which isn't a big problem IMHO! (Just set them in you build script)

Comment: Not a big problem, but unnecessary and annoying. So far, it's been enough to keep me from using it. Like I said, I prefer my code to *just work*.