# 'printf' vs. 'cout' in C++

Tags: c++, printf, iostream, cout, stdio

What is the difference between [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) and [`cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) in C++?

Comment: Nowadays (2023) there is a more modern alternative - see my answer below.

Answer (score 523):

I'm surprised that everyone in this question claims that `std::cout` is way better than `printf`, even if the question just asked for differences. Now, there is a difference - `std::cout` is C++, and `printf` is C (however, you can use it in C++, just like *almost* anything else from C). Now, I'll be honest here; both `printf` and `std::cout` have their advantages.

## Real differences

### Extensibility

`std::cout` is extensible. I know that people will say that `printf` is extensible too, but such extension is not mentioned in the C standard (so you would have to use non-standard features - but not even common non-standard feature exists), and such extensions are one letter (so it's easy to conflict with an already-existing format).

Unlike `printf`, `std::cout` depends completely on operator overloading, so there is no issue with custom formats - all you do is define a subroutine taking `std::ostream` as the first argument and your type as second. As such, there are no namespace problems - as long you have a class (which isn't limited to one character), you can have working `std::ostream` overloading for it.

However, I doubt that many people would want to extend `ostream` (to be honest, I rarely saw such extensions, even if they are easy to make). However, it's here if you need it.

### Syntax

As it could be easily noticed, both `printf` and `std::cout` use different syntax. `printf` uses standard function syntax using pattern string and variable-length argument lists. Actually, `printf` is a reason why C has them - `printf` formats are too complex to be usable without them. However, `std::cout` uses a different API - the `operator <<` API that returns itself.

Generally, that means the C version will be shorter, but in most cases it won't matter. The difference is noticeable when you print many arguments. If you have to write something like `Error 2: File not found.`, assuming error number, and its description is placeholder, the code would look like this. Both examples [work identically](http://codepad.org/uVKEdHfI) (well, sort of, `std::endl` actually flushes the buffer).

```
printf("Error %d: %s.\n", id, errors[id]);
std::cout << "Error " << id << ": " << errors[id] << "." << std::endl;
```

While this doesn't appear too crazy (it's just two times longer), things get more crazy when you actually format arguments, instead of just printing them. For example, printing of something like `0x0424` is just crazy. This is caused by `std::cout` mixing state and actual values. I never saw a language where something like `std::setfill` would be a type (other than C++, of course). `printf` clearly separates arguments and actual type. I really would prefer to maintain the `printf` version of it (even if it looks kind of cryptic) compared to `iostream` version of it (as it contains too much noise).

```
printf("0x%04x\n", 0x424);
std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << 0x424 << std::endl;
```

### Translation

This is where the real advantage of `printf` lies. The `printf` format string is well... a string. That makes it really easy to translate, compared to `operator <<` abuse of `iostream`. Assuming that the `gettext()` function translates, and you want to show `Error 2: File not found.`, the code to get translation of the previously shown format string would look like this:

```
printf(gettext("Error %d: %s.\n"), id, errors[id]);
```

Now, let's assume that we translate to Fictionish, where the error number is after the description. The translated string would look like `%2$s oru %1$d.\n`. Now, how to do it in C++? Well, I have no idea. I guess you can make fake `iostream` which constructs `printf` that you can pass to `gettext`, or something, for purposes of translation. Of course, `$` is not C standard, but it's so common that it's safe to use in my opinion.

### Not having to remember/look-up specific integer type syntax

C has lots of integer types, and so does C++. `std::cout` handles all types for you, while `printf` requires specific syntax depending on an integer type (there are non-integer types, but the only non-integer type you will use in practice with `printf` is `const char *` (C string, can be obtained using `to_c` method of `std::string`)). For instance, to print `size_t`, you need to use `%zu`, while `int64_t` will require using `%"PRId64"`. The tables are available at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer.

### You can't print the NUL byte, `\0`

Because `printf` uses C strings as opposed to C++ strings, it cannot print NUL byte without specific tricks. In certain cases it's possible to use `%c` with `'\0'` as an argument, although that's clearly a hack.

## Differences nobody cares about

### Performance

Update: It turns out that `iostream` is so slow that it's usually slower than your hard drive (if you redirect your program to file). Disabling synchronization with `stdio` may help, if you need to output lots of data. If the performance is a real concern (as opposed to writing several lines to STDOUT), just use `printf`.

Everyone thinks that they care about performance, but nobody bothers to measure it. My answer is that I/O is bottleneck anyway, no matter if you use `printf` or `iostream`. I think that `printf` *could* be faster from a quick look into assembly (compiled with clang using the `-O3` compiler option). Assuming my error example, `printf` example does way fewer calls than the `cout` example. This is `int main` with `printf`:

```
main:                                   @ @main
@ BB#0:
        push    {lr}
        ldr     r0, .LCPI0_0
        ldr     r2, .LCPI0_1
        mov     r1, #2
        bl      printf
        mov     r0, #0
        pop     {lr}
        mov     pc, lr
        .align  2
@ BB#1:
```

You can easily notice that two strings, and `2` (number) are pushed as `printf` arguments. That's about it; there is nothing else. For comparison, this is `iostream` compiled to assembly. No, there is no inlining; every single `operator <<` call means another call with another set of arguments.

```
main:                                   @ @main
@ BB#0:
        push    {r4, r5, lr}
        ldr     r4, .LCPI0_0
        ldr     r1, .LCPI0_1
        mov     r2, #6
        mov     r3, #0
        mov     r0, r4
        bl      _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
        mov     r0, r4
        mov     r1, #2
        bl      _ZNSolsEi
        ldr     r1, .LCPI0_2
        mov     r2, #2
        mov     r3, #0
        mov     r4, r0
        bl      _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
        ldr     r1, .LCPI0_3
        mov     r0, r4
        mov     r2, #14
        mov     r3, #0
        bl      _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
        ldr     r1, .LCPI0_4
        mov     r0, r4
        mov     r2, #1
        mov     r3, #0
        bl      _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
        ldr     r0, [r4]
        sub     r0, r0, #24
        ldr     r0, [r0]
        add     r0, r0, r4
        ldr     r5, [r0, #240]
        cmp     r5, #0
        beq     .LBB0_5
@ BB#1:                                 @ %_ZSt13__check_facetISt5ctypeIcEERKT_PS3_.exit
        ldrb    r0, [r5, #28]
        cmp     r0, #0
        beq     .LBB0_3
@ BB#2:
        ldrb    r0, [r5, #39]
        b       .LBB0_4
.LBB0_3:
        mov     r0, r5
        bl      _ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv
        ldr     r0, [r5]
        mov     r1, #10
        ldr     r2, [r0, #24]
        mov     r0, r5
        mov     lr, pc
        mov     pc, r2
.LBB0_4:                                @ %_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE5widenEc.exit
        lsl     r0, r0, #24
        asr     r1, r0, #24
        mov     r0, r4
        bl      _ZNSo3putEc
        bl      _ZNSo5flushEv
        mov     r0, #0
        pop     {r4, r5, lr}
        mov     pc, lr
.LBB0_5:
        bl      _ZSt16__throw_bad_castv
        .align  2
@ BB#6:
```

However, to be honest, this means nothing, as I/O is the bottleneck anyway. I just wanted to show that `iostream` is not faster because it's "type safe". Most C implementations implement `printf` formats using computed goto, so the `printf` is as fast as it can be, even without compiler being aware of `printf` (not that they aren't - some compilers can optimize `printf` in certain cases - constant string ending with `\n` is usually optimized to `puts`).

### Inheritance

I don't know why you would want to inherit `ostream`, but I don't care. It's possible with `FILE` too.

```
class MyFile : public FILE {}
```

### Type safety

True, variable length argument lists have no safety, but that doesn't matter, as popular C compilers can detect problems with `printf` format string if you enable warnings. In fact, Clang can do that without enabling warnings.

```
$ cat safety.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("String: %s\n", 42);
    return 0;
}

$ clang safety.c

safety.c:4:28: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("String: %s\n", 42);
                    ~~     ^~
                    %d
1 warning generated.
$ gcc -Wall safety.c
safety.c: In function ‘main’:
safety.c:4:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("String: %s\n", 42);
     ^
```

Comment: You say I/O is the bottleneck anyway.  Obviously you never [tested that assumption.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340396/does-the-c-standard-mandate-poor-performance-for-iostreams-or-am-i-just-deali)  I quote myself: "On the other hand, the iostreams version, at 75.3 MB/s, can't buffer data fast enough to keep up with a hard disk. That's bad, and it's not even doing any real work yet. I don't think I have too high expectations when I say my I/O library should be able to be able to saturate my disk controller."

Comment: @BenVoigt: I admit, I try to avoid C++ when possible. I tried using it a lot, but it was more annoying, and less maintainable than other programming language I used. This is yet another reason for me to avoid C++ - this isn't even fast (it's not even iostream - entire C++ library is slow in most implementations, perhaps with exception for `std::sort`, which is somehow surprisingly fast compared to `qsort` (2 times), at cost of executable size).

Comment: No one here has mentioned issues in parallel environment when using cout.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: Just don't print on multiple threads. This applies both to `std::cout` and `printf`. If you use multithreading for non-functional code (with side effects), you will be dealing with other, more serious issues. Locks don't help, they just make code slower than single threaded version of code. Don't use threads for performance without measuring it.

Comment: Your performance argument makes no sense whatsoever. More assembly in your program doesn't mean that program will be slower, because you're _not_ accounting for all the code that makes the printf function, which is a lot of code. In my opinion, it is possible to optimize cout with << operator a lot better than the printf, because compiler can make better sense of variables and formatting.

Comment: @Ignas2526: While true, it's also worth noting that implementation of C and C++ standard library is probably cached in memory. However, a huge program implemented in C or C++ may not be. The binary size [has impact on performance, especially launch performance](https://www.webkit.org/blog/2826/unusual-speed-boost-size-matters/). Also, `operator<<` is implemented as a separate function calls, the compiler has to know what `operator<<` does with file handle objects to optimize anything, which is tricky.  It's like `write(write(write(write(out, "0x"), hex), number), endl)` for a compiler.

Comment: @xfix: How printf() is also extensible?

Comment: @PravasiMeet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260170/is-this-possible-to-customize-printf

Comment: I like a lot of things about this answer, but perhaps my favorite part is "Everyone thinks that they care about performance, but nobody bothers to measure it."

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that C++ compilers typically spend a long time resolving overloaded insertion and extraction operators for iostream, I've read claims of about 33% of total compile time.

Comment: `c_str` is the method of `std::string` to obtain a C string, not `to_c`. Other than that, this is a kick-ass answer.

Comment: If I/O is the bottleneck, then it's _exactly_ the part of your program you should spend time speeding up!

Comment: The cout stuff is almost always more annoying to type, which is quite possibly the only thing I care about. If I want to mix in lots of variables, I need a ton of `<<`s and a ton of linebreaks. The stream syntax is just weird too; I see it used pretty much nowhere except cout. No thanks.

Comment: I've had many situations where I/O is, measurably, not my bottleneck. Databases for one. Even when copying a file, `pv` can't even come close to keeping up with my disk, so I use `dd` instead and send it interrupts to get status. But if you're running into that problem with your print statements, and you're not writing a "shell program" like `pv`, something else is probably wrong.

Comment: If you found `printf` faster than `cout`, then you used `endl`. Don't ever use `endl`.

Comment: Correct specifier for `size_t` is `%zu` and not `%zd`.

Answer (score 228):

From the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#iostream-vs-stdio):

> **[15.1] Why should I use `<iostream>`  instead of the traditional `<cstdio>`?**
>
> Increase type safety, reduce errors, allow extensibility, and provide inheritability.
>
> `printf()` is arguably not broken, and `scanf()` is perhaps livable despite being error prone, however both are limited with respect to what C++ I/O can do. C++ I/O (using `<<` and `>>`) is, relative to C (using `printf()` and `scanf()`):
>
> - More type-safe: With `<iostream>`, the type of object being I/O'd is
>     known statically by the compiler. In
>     contrast, `<cstdio>` uses "%" fields to
>     figure out the types dynamically.
> - Less error prone: With `<iostream>`, there are no redundant
>     "%" tokens that have to be consistent
>     with the actual objects being I/O'd.
>     Removing redundancy removes a class
>     of errors.
> - Extensible: The C++ `<iostream>` mechanism allows new user-defined
>     types to be I/O'd without breaking
>     existing code. Imagine the chaos if
>     everyone was simultaneously adding
>     new incompatible "%" fields to
>     `printf()` and `scanf()`?!
> - Inheritable: The C++ `<iostream>` mechanism is built from real classes
>     such as `std::ostream` and
>     `std::istream`. Unlike `<cstdio>`'s
>     `FILE*`, these are real classes and
>     hence inheritable. This means you can
>     have other user-defined things that
>     look and act like streams, yet that
>     do whatever strange and wonderful
>     things you want. You automatically
>     get to use the zillions of lines of
>     I/O code written by users you don't
>     even know, and they don't need to
>     know about your "extended stream"
>     class.

On the other hand, `printf` is significantly faster, which may justify using it in preference to `cout` in *very* specific and limited cases. Always profile first. (See, for example, [http://programming-designs.com/2009/02/c-speed-test-part-2-printf-vs-cout](https://web.archive.org/web/20131228104911/http://programming-designs.com/2009/02/c-speed-test-part-2-printf-vs-cout)/)

Comment: On the other other hand, there's the FastFormat library (http://www.fastformat.org), offering type-safety, expressivity and performance at once.  (Not that I tried it yet...)

Comment: How does such a poorly presented piece of copy-pasting, with no consideration for escaping (hence a rash of inexplicable omissions from the text) get _nine_ upvotes?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: I suspect a backlash to the accepted answer.

Comment: @xtofl yeah, I looked at it a while ago. Seemed promising, but rated dangerously high on my annoy-o-meter when I realized it depends on environment variables, which is one thing I really do not care to set up just for my code to compile.

Comment: @jalf: I knew there should have been something.... would you mind adding that to this, old, question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446276/is-there-a-catch-with-fastformat

Comment: @Marcelo probably because it's a good summary, with everything cited. The formatting... yeah, that's pretty bad. I should have fixed that myself, but it appears that others (yourself included) took care of it, which, of course, is more constructive than just whining.

Comment: As of late `printf()` is also supposed to be extensible. See "printf hooks" at http://udrepper.livejournal.com/20948.html

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Standard `printf` has no such ability.  Non-portable library mechanisms are hardly on the same level as fully standardized extensibility of iostreams.

Comment: "On the other hand, printf is significantly faster" printf is also cleaner and easier to use, which is why i avoid cout when possible.

Comment: "On the other hand, printf is significantly faster, which may justify using it in preference to cout". Is this true? The equivalent claim with cin/scanf is *not* true. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12762166/462335

Answer (score 56):

People often claim that `printf` is much faster. This is largely a myth. I just tested it, with the following results:

```
cout with only endl                     1461.310252 ms
cout with only '\n'                      343.080217 ms
printf with only '\n'                     90.295948 ms
cout with string constant and endl      1892.975381 ms
cout with string constant and '\n'       416.123446 ms
printf with string constant and '\n'     472.073070 ms
cout with some stuff and endl           3496.489748 ms
cout with some stuff and '\n'           2638.272046 ms
printf with some stuff and '\n'         2520.318314 ms
```

Conclusion: if you want only newlines, use `printf`; otherwise, `cout` is almost as fast, or even faster. More details can be found on [my blog](http://typethinker.blogspot.com/2010/05/are-c-iostreams-really-slow.html).

To be clear, I'm not trying to say that `iostream`s are always better than `printf`; I'm just trying to say that you should make an informed decision based on real data, not a wild guess based on some common, misleading assumption.

Update: Here's the full code I used for testing. Compiled with `g++` without any additional options (apart from `-lrt` for the timing).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

class TimedSection {
    char const *d_name;
    timespec d_start;
    public:
        TimedSection(char const *name) :
            d_name(name)
        {
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &d_start);
        }
        ~TimedSection() {
            timespec end;
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
            double duration = 1e3 * (end.tv_sec - d_start.tv_sec) +
                              1e-6 * (end.tv_nsec - d_start.tv_nsec);
            std::cerr << d_name << '\t' << std::fixed << duration << " ms\n"; 
        }
};

int main() {
    const int iters = 10000000;
    char const *text = "01234567890123456789";
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with only endl");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with only '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << '\n';
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("printf with only '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            printf("\n");
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with string constant and endl");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << "01234567890123456789" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with string constant and '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << "01234567890123456789\n";
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("printf with string constant and '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            printf("01234567890123456789\n");
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with some stuff and endl");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << text << "01234567890123456789" << i << std::endl;
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with some stuff and '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << text << "01234567890123456789" << i << '\n';
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("printf with some stuff and '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            printf("%s01234567890123456789%i\n", text, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: "more details on your blog"? Hardly. Your blog is missing the same details as this post: it doesn't tell us what you tested or how you tested it.

Comment: @jalf: You think? I linked instead of posting the full code here, because it's a bit long and repetitive. I definitely wrote there what I tested and how... the text on my blog should be sufficient to reproduce the code. But I've edited it into my post... is that sufficient?

Comment: In your scores printf beats cout easily (majority cases). I wonder why you recommend using cout when it comes to perf. Though I agree perf is not too different in realistic cases..

Comment: @mishal153: I'm just trying to say that the performance is not too different, so the commonly-heard advice of "never use cout because it's waaay slow" is plain stupid. Note that cout has the obvious advantage of type-safety, and often readability as well. (Floating-point formatting with iostreams is horrible...)

Comment: @Thomas: "reproducing the code" wouldn't necessarily reproduce your results. In order to know if your benchmarks are valid, we need to be able to look at the code. But yeah, thanks for adding the code. :)

Comment: @Thomas: I tested your code on a Ubuntu 10.04 (gcc 4.4.3), and came out with similar results (note that the cout was somewhat faster than printf for small strings like `"\n"`).

Comment: The important difference between `printf()` and `std::ostream` is that **the former outputs all arguments in one single call** whereas `std::ostream` incurs a separate call for each `<<`. The test only outputs one argument and a new-line, that's why you can't see the difference.

Comment: The compiler should be able to inline these calls. Also, `printf` might make a lot of calls under the covers to helper functions for various formatting specifiers... that, or it's a monstrous monolithic function. And again, because of inlining, it shouldn't make a difference in speed at all.

Comment: Thomas. You're wrong. I made a couple of console based games which required me to render to a string. Printf was always alot faster than cout.

Comment: I never said anything about rendering to a string. That'd be `sprintf` versus `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: @Thomas: It's not able to. I checked with newest versions of gcc and Clang with `-S -O3` options.

Comment: You timed your terminal.  Use `sprintf` or `fprintf` and `stringstream` or `fstream`.

Comment: Not necessarily. It's true that the system calls will likely be a bottleneck, but this should be included in the benchmark. If one alternative does more/slower syscalls than the other, we want to know. I think without the I/O operations, any such difference (even if it's relatively large) is likely to be irrelevant compared to the rest of the things the program is doing.

Comment: cout with endl is equivalent to printf with fflush.

Comment: did you have cpu boost activate while running benchmarks?

Comment: @sciencefyll What is cpu boost?

Comment: When running benchmarks most people just write them on their everyday PC. These utilize boost to handle demand and to save power when they arent needed. When you run a benchmark you should force your CPU to have a constant speed. Otherwise the results aren't accurate

Answer (score 44):

And I [quote](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/62629-c-printf-vs-cout):

> In high level terms, the main differences are type safety (cstdio
>   doesn't have it), performance (most iostreams implementations are
>   slower than the cstdio ones) and extensibility (iostreams allows
>   custom output targets and seamless output of user defined types).

Comment: Especially on unix where with POSIX you never know what size one of the  typedefs really has so you need  lots of casts or as 99% of the programs you just risk it with %d. Took even a long time before %z  came with C99. 

But for time_t/off_t  the quest for the correct format instruction continues.

Answer (score 31):

One is a function that prints to stdout. The other is an object that provides several member functions and overloads of `operator<<` that print to stdout. There are many more differences that I could enumerate, but I'm not sure what you are after.

Answer (score 13):

For me, the real differences which would make me go for 'cout' rather than 'printf' are:

1) **<<** operator can be overloaded for my classes.

2) Output stream for cout can be easily changed to a file :
(: copy paste :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "This is sent to prompt" << endl;
    ofstream file;
    file.open ("test.txt");
    streambuf* sbuf = cout.rdbuf();
    cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());
    cout << "This is sent to file" << endl;
    cout.rdbuf(sbuf);
    cout << "This is also sent to prompt" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

3) I find cout more readable, especially when we have many parameters.

One **problem** with `cout` is the formatting options. Formatting the data (precision, justificaton, etc.) in `printf` is easier.

Comment: it's nice. How can I know nobody modify global cout this way in some foreign library thread?

Comment: You can easily change `printf` to a file as well by replacing it with `fprintf`...

Answer (score 9):

Two points not otherwise mentioned here that I find significant:

1) `cout` carries a lot of baggage if you're not already using the STL. It adds over twice as much code to your object file as `printf`. This is also true for `string`, and this is the major reason I tend to use my own string library.

2) `cout` uses overloaded `<<` operators, which I find unfortunate. This can add confusion if you're also using the `<<` operator for its intended purpose (shift left). I personally don't like to overload operators for purposes tangential to their intended use.

Bottom line: I'll use `cout` (and `string`) if I'm already using the STL. Otherwise, I tend to avoid it.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a programmer, but I have been a human factors engineer. I feel a programming language should be easy to learn, understand and use, and this requires that it have a simple and consistent linguistic structure. Although all the languages is symbolic and thus, at its core, arbitrary, there are conventions and following them makes the language easier to learn and use.

There are a vast number of functions in C++ and other languages written as function(parameter), a syntax that was originally used for functional relationships in mathematics in the pre-computer era. `printf()` follows this syntax and if the writers of C++ wanted to create any logically different method for reading and writing files they could have simply created a different function using a similar syntax.

In Python we of course can print using the also fairly standard `object.method` syntax, i.e. variablename.print, since variables are objects, but in C++ they are not.

I'm not fond of the cout syntax because the << operator does not follow any rules. It is a method or function, i.e. it takes a parameter and does something to it. However it is written as though it were a mathematical comparison operator. This is a poor approach from a human factors standpoint.

Comment: << is not a comparison operator. It is the bit shift left operator. It takes two integer arguments (originally). 10 << 1; This shifts the bits of ten 1 time(s) to the left; returning the number 20. But Cpp allows operator overloading and decides to use this operator for stdout. The comparison operators of cpp are less than(<) greater than(>) less than or equal(<=) greater than or equal(>=) equal(==) not equal(!=). It's all just syntax specific to cpp and not directly from Maths. Note that assignment operator is(=).

Answer (score 4):

With primitives, it probably doesn't matter entirely which one you use. I say where it gets usefulness is when you want to output complex objects.

For example, if you have a class,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Something
{
public:
        Something(int x, int y, int z) : a(x), b(y), c(z) { }
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Something&);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Something& s)
{
        o << s.a << ", " << s.b << ", " << s.c;
        return o;
}

int main(void)
{
        Something s(3, 2, 1);

        // output with printf
        printf("%i, %i, %i\n", s.a, s.b, s.c);

        // output with cout
        cout << s << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Now the above might not seem all that great, but let's suppose you have to output this in multiple places in your code. Not only that, let's say you add a field "int d." With cout, you only have to change it in once place. However, with printf, you'd have to change it in possibly a lot of places and not only that, you have to remind yourself which ones to output.

With that said, with cout, you can reduce a lot of times spent with maintenance of your code and not only that if you re-use the object "Something" in a new application, you don't really have to worry about output.

Comment: Also, to add about the performance thing, I'd say that you shouldn't output anything at all if your application is made for performance. Any sort of output to std is rather expensive and slow. I say you should avoid it and only output when it is absolutely necessary to do so.

Comment: keep in mind that your class might have private members you cannot access so easily from the outside. With the output operator, you have exactly one location that needs to be friend to your class, and now you can output it anywhere, even in code you didn't know about.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to point out that if you want to play with threads in C++, if you use `cout` you can get some interesting results.

Consider this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void task(int taskNum, string msg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cout << "#" << taskNum << ": " << msg << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    thread t1(task, 1, "AAA");
    thread t2(task, 2, "BBB");
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}

// g++ ./thread.cpp -o thread.out -ansi -pedantic -pthread -std=c++0x
```

Now, the output comes all shuffled. It can yield different results too, try executing several times:

```
##12::  ABABAB

##12::  ABABAB

##12::  ABABAB

##12::  ABABAB

##12::  ABABAB
```

You can use `printf` to get it right, or you can use `mutex`.

```
#1: AAA
#2: BBB
#1: AAA
#2: BBB
#1: AAA
#2: BBB
#1: AAA
#2: BBB
#1: AAA
#2: BBB
```

Have fun!

Comment: wtf `thread`s don't make output go nuts. I just reproduced and found both `xyz` and `ABC` in the output. There was not mangling b/w `ABC` as `ABABAB`.

Comment: I don't know how `cout` works with threads, but I know for sure that the code you are showing isn't the one that you used to get those outputs. Your code passes the string `"ABC"` for thread 1 and `"xyz"` for thread 2, but your output shows `AAA` and `BBB`. Please fix it, because right now it's confusing.

Comment: `cout` make things interleave because as the other answers pointed out, `cout` will not run as a single call, but will run in a chain of calls, so they will eventually interleave. But differently from what @Apollo mentioned, it won't ever interleave `A` and `B` since `msg` will print in a single call. But it can print something like `#2: AAABBB`.

Comment: It's no longer relevant. The secret is in the compile command : `-std=c++0x`. Using a c++ standard that is not 10 year old and this issue will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

**API**

[`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) uses a replacement-based API with placeholders starting with `%` replaced with formatted arguments:

```cpp
printf("The answer is %d.\n", answer);
```

[`cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) or, more generally, ostreams use a concatenation-based API with parts of a formatted message interleaved with arguments:

```cpp
std::cout << "The answer is " << answer << ".\n";
```

A replacement-based API with proper synchronization provides atomicity, e.g. when writing from multiple threads different messages written with `printf` won't interleave while parts of the messages written with `cout` may interleave. For this reason C++20 introduced [`std::osyncstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream) which is a clunky way of achieving atomicity.

With operator overloading formatting can quickly become cumbersome, e.g.

```cpp
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << 1.23456 << "\n";
```

vs

```cpp
printf("%.2f\n", 1.23456);
```

Matthew Wilson, the author of FastFormat, called this ["chevron hell"](https://accu.org/journals/overload/17/89/wilson_1539/).

**Extensibility**

`cout` supports formatting of user-defined types through overloading of `operator<<`. There is no standard way to do the same with `printf`, although there is a [glibc extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html) which is rarely used in practice.

**Safety**

`printf` uses varargs which are inherently unsafe unless you use something like GCC's [`format` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) which only works with literal format strings. It is a user's responsibility to correctly pass type information via format specifiers. Any mismatch results in an undefined behavior and is a [common source of vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Format_string_attack).

`cout`/ostreams are type-safe and the user doesn't need to manually handle type information.

**Buffering**

`cout` adds another layer of buffering and synchronizes with the underlying C streams by default. This brings significant performance overhead. It is possible to disable this synchronization at the cost of worse interoperability with C and potentially other languages.

**Formatting state**

In `printf` formatting is controlled via a format string and decoupled from the stream itself. In `cout`/ostreams the formatting state is stored in the stream which may negatively affect performance and cause unexpected results. Quoting [N4412: Shortcomings of iostreams](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4412.html):

> Formatting parameters (such as uppercase/lowercase and radix) are specified by setting flags, which mostly persist for an arbitrary number of subsequent low-level formatting operations, until explicitly changed. This approach inhibits compile-time checks and compile-time choice of formatting, and potentially establishes state shared between threads (which requires synchronization for access).

**Locales**

`printf` uses the global C locale.

`cout` uses the C++ locale associated with the stream.

Both `printf` and `cout` use locales by default.

**Performance**

`cout` is often slower than `printf` for reasons mentioned above: extra buffering and synchronization (can be disabled) and stateful API.

**Language**

`printf` is a part of the C standard library and can be used in C and C++. `cout` is a part of the C++ standard library and can only be used in C++.

---

You can have the best of both worlds by using C++23 [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print). It provides a replacement-based API with positional arguments. It is extensible, type-safe, doesn't introduce extra buffering and makes localized formatting an opt-in.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of C++23 `std::print`.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout<< "Hello";
printf("%s", "Hello");
```

Both are used to print values. They have completely different syntax. C++ has both, C
only has printf.

Comment: ... what?  did you mixup something?

Comment: Fixed the issue. -1 because it required fixing and the answer leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: The function names had been reversed: cout was used with the printf syntax, and printf was used with the cout syntax. Shouldn't have even been accepted!

Comment: The main advantage of cout is that it uses operator<< which can be overloaded for complex types

Comment: and the main disadvantage of cout is that it uses operator<< which is verbose and ugly and arguably operator abuse. :)

Comment: I'm a little confused. Why was this answer accepted with a -6 vote?

Comment: It was first positive and then quickly dropped because of the incorrect example

Comment: (why am i still on this thread..!@!#) the example is correct syntactically AFAIK. Problem with this answer is that there are plenty of differences, not just syntax :)

Comment: Although this is certainty not the best answer, I don't understand how scatman is being punished for his answer only because it was picked as the best answer. xbit has a way worse answer IMO but has -1 vote. I'm not saying xbit should be down voted any more, but I don't see it being fair to down vote scatman for the OP's mistake anymore than it has to be...

Comment: @Jesse: the downvotes are because the first revision of the answer was *completely* wrong. And most of the people who downvoted then haven't seen that it's been fixed since then. I just cancelled my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can write "something" a bit better to keep maintenance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Something
{
    public:
        Something(int x, int y, int z) : a(x), b(y), c(z) { }
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Something&);

        void print() const { printf("%i, %i, %i\n", a, b, c); }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Something& s)
{
    o << s.a << ", " << s.b << ", " << s.c;
    return o;
}

int main(void)
{
    Something s(3, 2, 1);

    // Output with printf
    s.print(); // Simple as well, isn't it?

    // Output with cout
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And a bit extended test of cout vs. printf, added a test of 'double', if anyone wants to do more testing (Visual Studio 2008, release version of the executable):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

class TimedSection {
    char const *d_name;
    //timespec d_start;
    clock_t d_start;

    public:
        TimedSection(char const *name) :
            d_name(name)
        {
            //clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &d_start);
            d_start = clock();
        }
        ~TimedSection() {
            clock_t end;
            //clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
            end = clock();
            double duration = /*1e3 * (end.tv_sec - d_start.tv_sec) +
                              1e-6 * (end.tv_nsec - d_start.tv_nsec);
                              */
                              (double) (end - d_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

            std::cerr << d_name << '\t' << std::fixed << duration * 1000.0 << " ms\n";
        }
};


int main() {
    const int iters = 1000000;
    char const *text = "01234567890123456789";
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with only endl");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with only '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << '\n';
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("printf with only '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            printf("\n");
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with string constant and endl");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << "01234567890123456789" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with string constant and '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << "01234567890123456789\n";
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("printf with string constant and '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            printf("01234567890123456789\n");
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with some stuff and endl");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << text << "01234567890123456789" << i << std::endl;
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with some stuff and '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << text << "01234567890123456789" << i << '\n';
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("printf with some stuff and '\\n'");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            printf("%s01234567890123456789%i\n", text, i);
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with formatted double (width & precision once)");
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::scientific << std::right << std::showpoint;
        std::cout.width(8);
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            std::cout << text << 8.315 << i << '\n';
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("cout with formatted double (width & precision on each call)");
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::scientific << std::right << std::showpoint;

        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            { std::cout.width(8);
              std::cout.precision(3);
              std::cout << text << 8.315 << i << '\n';
            }
    }
    {
        TimedSection s("printf with formatted double");
        for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
            printf("%8.3f%i\n", 8.315, i);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
cout with only endl    6453.000000 ms
cout with only '\n'    125.000000 ms
printf with only '\n'    156.000000 ms
cout with string constant and endl    6937.000000 ms
cout with string constant and '\n'    1391.000000 ms
printf with string constant and '\n'    3391.000000 ms
cout with some stuff and endl    9672.000000 ms
cout with some stuff and '\n'    7296.000000 ms
printf with some stuff and '\n'    12235.000000 ms
cout with formatted double (width & precision once)    7906.000000 ms
cout with formatted double (width & precision on each call)    9141.000000 ms
printf with formatted double    3312.000000 ms
```

Comment: Wow, why is `endl` so much less efficient than `'\n'`?

Comment: I believe it's because `endl` flushes the buffer, and `\n` does not, although I'm not sure this is definitively the reason why.

Comment: This is not an asnwer to the question, it's more like an answer to [Daniel's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876519/3982001) and [Thomas's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2873251/3982001).

Comment: @CalebXu, nope, you're right; that's the only reason why. If you look at the definition for std::endl `template <class _Elem, class _Traits>
basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> &__CLRCALL_OR_CDECL
endl(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> &_Ostr) { // insert newline and flush stream
  _Ostr.put(_Ostr.widen('\n'));
  _Ostr.flush();
  return _Ostr;
}` it literally inserts a newline and flushes the stream.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2023:**

The idiomatic way to print to the console from c++23 is supposed to be with [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print), which uses `{}` placeholders in the format string syntax (see below):

```
#include <print>

int main()
{
    std::print("{}, {} !", "Hello", "world");
}
```

However as of now, the compilers support for it is very poor.

Meanwhile we can use the **{fmt}** library for a similar API.
Note that the c++ standard is actually based (mostly) on a subset of **{fmt}**.
See more about it here: [What are the differences between libfmt and std::format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586747/what-are-the-differences-between-libfmt-and-stdformat).
For more info about the format string syntax see here: [{fmt} Format String Syntax](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html).

Working example:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main()
{
    fmt::print("{}, {} !", "Hello", "world");
}
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4PKdKTMKj)

Answer (score 1):

I would like say that extensibility lack of `printf` is not entirely true:
In C, it is true. But in C, there are no real classes.
In C++, it is possible to overload cast operator, so, overloading a `char*` operator and using `printf` like this:

```
Foo bar;
...;
printf("%s",bar);
```

can be possible, if Foo overload the good operator. Or if you made a good method. In short, `printf` is as extensible as `cout` for me.

Technical argument I can see for C++ streams (in general... not only cout.) are:

- Typesafety. (And, by the way, if I want to print a single `'\n'` I use `putchar('\n')`... I will not use a nuke-bomb to kill an insect.).
- Simpler to learn. (no "complicated" parameters to learn, just to use `<<` and `>>` operators)
- Work natively with `std::string` (for `printf` there is `std::string::c_str()`, but for `scanf`?)

For `printf` I see:

- Easier, or at least shorter (in term of characters written) complex formatting. Far more readable, *for me* (matter of taste I guess).
- Better control of what the function made (Return how many characters where written and there is the `%n` formatter: "Nothing printed. The argument must be a pointer to a signed int, where the number of characters written so far is stored." (from [printf - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/))
- Better debugging possibilities. For same reason as last argument.

My personal preferences go to `printf` (and `scanf`) functions, mainly because I love short lines, and because I don't think type problems on printing text are really hard to avoid.
The only thing I deplore with C-style functions is that `std::string` is not supported. We have to go through a `char*` before giving it to `printf` (with the `std::string::c_str()` if we want to read, but how to write?)

Comment: The compiler has no type information for varargs functions, so it won't convert the actual parameter (except *default argument promotions*, such as standard integral promotions).  See 5.2.2p7.  A user-defined conversion to `char*` won't be used.

Comment: Even if this worked, it wouldn't be an example of sprintf extensibility, just a clever hack to give sprintf what it expects, and it ignores some serious issues such as where the `char*` lives and for how long, and the dangers of user-defined implicit casts.

Answer (score 1):

More differences:
"printf" returns an integer value (equal to the number of characters printed) and "cout" does not return anything

And.

`cout << "y = " << 7;` is not atomic.

`printf("%s = %d", "y", 7);` is atomic.

cout performs typechecking, printf doesn't.

There's no iostream equivalent of `"% d"`

Comment: `cout` doesn't return anything because it's an object, not a function. `operator<<` does return something (normally its left operand, but a false value if there's an error). And in what sense is the `printf` call "atomic"?

Comment: It is like an atomic bomb. `printf("%s\n",7);`

Comment: @artlessnoise wait why segmentation fault? `%s` is ?

Comment: That is the point of the 'atomic bomb' statement.  A `printf` *%s* argument must have a valid pointer to a null terminated string.  The memory range '7' (a pointer) is not usually valid; a segmentation fault could be lucky.  On some systems, '7' might print a lot of garbage to a console and you would have to look at it for a day before the program stops.  In other words, this is a bad thing about `printf`.  Static analysis tools can catch many of these issues.

Comment: While technically `printf` doesn't do typechecking, I've never ever used a compiler that didn't warn me about type errors with `printf`...

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Always do your own research, in regard of **generated machine code size**, **performance**, **readability** and **coding time** before trusting random comments online, including this one.

I'm no expert. I just happened to overhear two co-workers talking about how we should avoid using C++ in embedded systems because of performance issues. Well, interesting enough, I did a benchmark based on a real project task.

In said task, we had to write some config to RAM. Something like:

> coffee=hot
>   sugar=none
>   milk=breast
>   mac=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF

Here's my benchmark programs (Yes, I know OP asked about printf(), not fprintf(). Try to capture the essence and by the way, OP's link points to fprintf() anyway.)

C program:

```
char coffee[10], sugar[10], milk[10];
unsigned char mac[6];

/* Initialize those things here. */

FILE * f = fopen("a.txt", "wt");

fprintf(f, "coffee=%s\nsugar=%s\nmilk=%s\nmac=%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n", coffee, sugar, milk, mac[0], mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]);

fclose(f);
```

C++ program:

```
//Everything else is identical except:

std::ofstream f("a.txt", std::ios::out);

f << "coffee=" << coffee << "\n";
f << "sugar=" << sugar << "\n";
f << "milk=" << milk << "\n";
f << "mac=" << (int)mac[0] << ":"
    << (int)mac[1] << ":"
    << (int)mac[2] << ":"
    << (int)mac[3] << ":"
    << (int)mac[4] << ":"
    << (int)mac[5] << endl;
f.close();
```

I did my best to polish them before I looped them both 100,000 times. Here are the results:

C program:

```
real    0m 8.01s
user    0m 2.37s
sys     0m 5.58s
```

C++ program:

```
real    0m 6.07s
user    0m 3.18s
sys     0m 2.84s
```

Object file size:

```
C   - 2,092 bytes
C++ - 3,272 bytes
```

Conclusion: On my very specific **platform**, with a very specific **processor**, running a very specific version of **Linux kernel**, to run a program which is compiled with a very specific version of **GCC**, in order to accomplish a very specific **task**, I would say the C++ approach is more suitable because it runs significantly faster and provide much better readability. On the other hand, C offers small footprint, in my opinion, means nearly nothing because program size is not of our concern.

Remeber, YMMV.

Comment: I disagree that C++ is more readable in this example, because your example packs multiple lines into a single printf call. That is naturally less readable than the way you did the C++ code, and is rarely done in C because its hard to read and hard to maintain. A fair comparison would spread out the C into separate printfs, one for reach line.

Comment: @maharvey67 It's true what you said. However, the example I provided in C was in consideration of performance. The packed-in-one call to fprintf was two seconds slower than the C++ equivalence already. If I were to make the C code readable then it might be even slower. Disclaimer: This was one year ago and I remember I tried my best to polish both C and C++ code. I had no proof of separated calls to fprintf would be faster than one single call, but the reason I did it this way probably indicates that it wasn't.

Comment: *I would say the C++ approach is more suitable because it runs significantly faster and provide much better readability* I wouldn't.  The C++ version took 3.18 seconds of user time while the C version took only 2.37 seconds of user time.  That means the C binary was much more efficient in doing its user-space work, and the entirety of the performance difference is due to the system time being much lower for the C++ version.  Since you neglected to specify how the IO was actually being performed by the compiled binaries, there's no way to tell ***why*** the C++ binary used less system time.

Comment: It could be something mundane as the C++ output being buffered differently.  It could be because of locking in the C calls.  How about benchmarking `sprintf()` and then `write()` using 'O_DIRECT'?

Answer (score -5):

`printf` is a function whereas `cout` is a variable.

Comment: I did a roll-back because, although the answer itself may be wrong, it is still a genuine answer. If you (correctly) think the answer is wrong, you have two options: 1) add a comment or 2) add a new answer (or do both). Don't change someone's answer to such that it says something completely different from what was intended by the author.

Comment: `printf` is a function, but `printf()` is a function call =)

Comment: cout is an object, not a variable.