# Is this possible to customize printf?

Tags: c, linux, customization, glibc

I have some struct that I need to print frequently. For now, I am using a classical print wrapper around this struct :

```
void printf_mystruct(struct* my_struct)
{
   if (my_struct==NULL) return;
   printf("[value1:%d value2:%d]", struct->value1, struct->value2);
}
```

This function is handy, but is also really limited. I cannot prepen or append some text without making a new wrapper. I know that I can use **va_arg** family to be able to prepend or apprend some text, but I feel like I would be re-implementing the wheel.

I am wondering if it's possible to write a customizing function to printf. I would like to be able to write something like this :

```
register2printf("%mys", &printf_mystruct); 
...
if (incorrect)
  printf("[%l] Struct is incorrect : %mys\n", log_level, my_struct);
```

Is this possible ? How can I do this ?

NB: I am under Ubuntu Linux 10.04 and I use gcc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<sup>Sorry, but some answers are incorrect on Linux with Glibc</sup>

On Linux with a GNU Glibc, you can [customize printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html): you would call 
`register_printf_function` to e.g. define the meaning of `%Y` in your `printf` format strings.

However, this behavior is Glibc specific, and might even become obsolete... I'm not sure I would recommend this approach!

If coding in C++, the C++ stream library has manipulators which you could extend, and you can also overload for your types the `operator <<`  etc.

#### added in february 2018

You could consider writing a [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) helping that (and improving the typechecking of some extended `printf`). It won't be easy (probably a few weeks or months of work), and it would be GCC version specific (not the same plugin code for GCC 7 and GCC 8). you might add some specific `#pragma` to inform your plugin about extra control string specifiers like your `%Y` and the type expected for them. Your plugin should change the handling of `format` attribute (perhaps in `gcc/tree.c`)

Comment: can you detail why you wouldn't recommend this approach ? Is there a better approach in C ?

Comment: Yes, it is fun. But you will have to recompile all glibc for the sake of one function.

Comment: No, you don't need to compile Glibc. You just need to call `register_printf_function` from a program using Glibc (that is, any Linux program in C or C++). However, that won't work on non Glibc systems (e.g. on MacOSX or FreeBSD). It practically works mostly on Linux.

Comment: I have found a sample implementation [here](http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=3874&action=view).

Comment: I don't recommend using that because it is not standard (you need GNU Glibc!). and I am not sure that it is often used, so it might be obsoleted on the long run.

Comment: You can easily wrap the places that need the extension is a macro like `SPECIAL_PRINTF()`.  Porting to a non-glibc platform would require writing some printf wrapper to handle the extra formatting.  At least this would make migration easier (if it is ever needed) and give no overhead for the glibc case.

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if there exists a plugin to make gcc not warn about such custom specifiers. I ask you, because you know well about gcc plugins. I was trying to write one that does this, but I am a little bit lost because documentation is not that great. So if you have any extra information that might be useful, please share it with me so that I can write the plugin. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, no there is no such plugin

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: added more stuff about such a plugin. But beware, you'll need *weeks* of work at least.

Comment: Thaks. I did read it. It's a shame, because I was hoping to write such a useful now that I have little work. However, if I get the time and succeed at writing it I'll let you know.

Comment: As you predicted, `register_printf_function()` has been deprecated.  However, a newer function has been added: `register_printf_specifier()`.  It's usage is very similar to the old one.  I wrote an example to register the `%b` specifier for printing unsigned integral types in binary, which you can see on CodeReview: [c - Register “%b” conversion specifier](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/219994/200418).

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible in standard C. You cannot extend `printf` to add custom format strings. Your helper function approach is probably about as good as you will get within the constraints of C.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. An alternative is to make your own wrapper around `printf()` itself. It would parse the format string and process conversions like `printf()` does. If a conversion is one of your custom conversions, it would print whatever you need, and if not, it would call one of the system's `*printf()` functions to have it perform the conversion for you.

Note that this is a non-trivial task, and you have to be careful to parse the format string exactly like `printf()` does. See `man 3 printf`. You can read the variable argument list using functions in `<stdarg.h>`.

Once you have such a wrapper, you can make it extensible by employing function pointers (the custom conversions don't have to be hard-coded into the wrapper).

Comment: With Linux and Glibc you can customize `printf`. See my answer!

Comment: You can do your wrapper simpler by just transforming your data to a string before and then in your wrapper just replace your custom specifier by `s` and call the normal printf with your output string, if you don't want specific flags to have other behaviors than on %s it can do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) function to obtain a string representation of your struct:

```
char* repr_mystruct(char* buffer, struct* my_struct)
{
    sprintf(buffer, "[string:%s value1:%d value2:%d]", struct->value1, struct->value2);
    return buffer;
}
```

and subsequently print the data to your output stream

```
char buffer[512]; //However large you need it to be
printf("My struct is: %s", repr_mystruct(buffer, &my_struct))
```

Edit: Modified the function to allow the passing of a buffer (see discussion below).

Note 2: The format string requires three arguments but in the example only two are passed.

Comment: Yes there are problems. That's UB since the local variable is only valid inside its function. You would have to pass the buffer in.

Comment: This is wrong. Buffer goes out of scope when the function returns, and as such the returned pointer is invalid. One possible solution is to use a buffer variable on file scope (global). However this is problematic when you need to print multiple structs in the same printf (there are no sequence points between argument evaluations). A nice solution is to have N global buffers, and an argument to repr_mystruct() telling it which of the N buffers to use. Then in a single printf() you make sure to pass a different buffer index to every repr_mystruct().

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak The nice solution is to pass the buffer in as a parameter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well that depends. Passing an integer surely takes less code than passing a buffer (and possibly obtaining a buffer in the first place).

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak If you don't use threads and you don't ever have re-entrancy then your approach would work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan true, that assumes your program is single-threaded and that the repr_mystruct() doesn't call itself recursively; which is not an insane assumption. If you use threads, a lock around the buffer would make it thread-safe.

Comment: Modified the above to allow the passing of a buffer explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible.

Probably the easiest solution would be taking a small `printf` implementation (e.g. from a libc for embedded systems) and extending it to fit your purposes.

Comment: With Linux and Glibc you can customize `printf`. See my answer!

Comment: I have used an [`snprintf` implementation](https://www.ijs.si/software/snprintf/) for this purpose.  With `snprintf`, you need space for the formatted string in memory.  This is sufficient for many use cases.  You can send the formatted string to what ever file you like (stdout included).  I guess that ties this answer to Basile's porting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it here:

```
printf("%s: pid = %lu, ppid = %lu, pgrp = %lu, tpgrp = %lu\n", name, 
        (unsigned long int)getpid(), (unsigned long int)getppid(), (unsigned long int)getpgrp(), 
        (unsigned long int)tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want portable code, the glibc extensions are out. But even keeping to C99 and POSIX standards it is very much possible, I just wrote one.

You don't have to re-implement printf, you do unfortunately need to make your code smart enough to parse printf format strings, and infer the variadic argument's C types from them.

When variadic arguments are placed on the stack, no type or sizing information is included.

```
void my_variadic_func(fmt, ...)
{

}

my_variadic_func("%i %s %i", 1, "2", 3);
```

In the above example on a 64bit system, with 48bit addressing the compiler would likely end up allocating 4bytes + 6bytes + 4byte = 14bytes of stack memory, and packing the values into that. I say likely, because how the memory is allocated and the arguments packed is implementation specific.

That means, in order to access the pointer value for `%s` in the above string, you need to know that the first argument was of type `int`, so you can advance your va_list cursor to the right point.

The only way you can get that type information is by looking at the format string, and seeing what type the user specified (in this case `%i`).

So in order to implement @AmbrozBizjak's suggestion, of passing subfmt strings to printf, you need to parse the fmt string, and after each complete, non-custom fmt specifier, advance a va_list by (however many bytes wide) the fmt type was.

When you hit a custom fmt specifier, your va_list is at the right point to unpack the argument. You can then use `va_arg()` to get your custom argument (passing the right type), and use it to run whatever code you need to, to produce your custom fmt specifier's output.

You concatenate the output from your previous printf call, and your custom fmt specifier's output, and carry on processing, until you reach the end, at which point you call printf again to process the rest of your format string.

The code is more complex (so I included it below), but that gives you a basic idea of what you have to do.

My code also uses talloc... but you can do it with the standard memory functions, just requires a bit more string wrangling.

```
char *custom_vasprintf(TALLOC_CTX *ctx, char const *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    char const  *p = fmt, *end = p + strlen(fmt), *fmt_p = p, *fmt_q = p;
    char        *out = NULL, *out_tmp;
    va_list     ap_p, ap_q;

    out = talloc_strdup(ctx, "");
    va_copy(ap_p, ap);
    va_copy(ap_q, ap_p);

    do {

        char        *q;
        char        *custom;
        char        len[2] = { '\0', '\0' };
        long        width = 0, group = 0, precision = 0, tmp;

        if ((*p != '%') || (*++p == '%')) {
            fmt_q = p + 1;
            continue;   /* literal char */
        }

        /*
         *  Check for parameter field
         */
        tmp = strtoul(p, &q, 10);
        if ((q != p) && (*q == '$')) {
            group = tmp;
            p = q + 1;
        }

        /*
         *  Check for flags
         */
        do {
            switch (*p) {
            case '-':
                continue;

            case '+':
                continue;

            case ' ':
                continue;

            case '0':
                continue;

            case '#':
                continue;

            default:
                goto done_flags;
            }
        } while (++p < end);
    done_flags:

        /*
         *  Check for width field
         */
        if (*p == '*') {
            width = va_arg(ap_q, int);
            p++;
        } else {
            width = strtoul(p, &q, 10);
            p = q;
        }

        /*
         *  Check for precision field
         */
        if (*p == '.') {
            p++;
            precision = strtoul(p, &q, 10);
            p = q;
        }

        /*
         *  Length modifiers
         */
        switch (*p) {
        case 'h':
        case 'l':
            len[0] = *p++;
            if ((*p == 'h') || (*p == 'l')) len[1] = *p++;
            break;

        case 'L':
        case 'z':
        case 'j':
        case 't':
            len[0] = *p++;
            break;
        }

        /*
         *  Types
         */
        switch (*p) {
        case 'i':                               /* int */
        case 'd':                               /* int */
        case 'u':                               /* unsigned int */
        case 'x':                               /* unsigned int */
        case 'X':                               /* unsigned int */
        case 'o':                               /* unsigned int */
            switch (len[0]) {
            case 'h':
                if (len[1] == 'h') {                    /* char (promoted to int) */
                    (void) va_arg(ap_q, int);
                } else {
                    (void) va_arg(ap_q, int);           /* short (promoted to int) */
                }
                break;

            case 'L':
                if ((*p == 'i') || (*p == 'd')) {
                    if (len [1] == 'L') {
                        (void) va_arg(ap_q, long);      /* long */
                    } else {
                        (void) va_arg(ap_q, long long);     /* long long */
                    }
                } else {
                    if (len [1] == 'L') {
                        (void) va_arg(ap_q, unsigned long); /* unsigned long */
                    } else {
                        (void) va_arg(ap_q, unsigned long long);/* unsigned long long */
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 'z':
                (void) va_arg(ap_q, size_t);                /* size_t */
                break;

            case 'j':
                (void) va_arg(ap_q, intmax_t);              /* intmax_t */
                break;

            case 't':
                (void) va_arg(ap_q, ptrdiff_t);             /* ptrdiff_t */
                break;

            case '\0':  /* no length modifier */
                if ((*p == 'i') || (*p == 'd')) {
                    (void) va_arg(ap_q, int);           /* int */
                } else {
                    (void) va_arg(ap_q, unsigned int);      /* unsigned int */
                }
            }
            break;

        case 'f':                               /* double */
        case 'F':                               /* double */
        case 'e':                               /* double */
        case 'E':                               /* double */
        case 'g':                               /* double */
        case 'G':                               /* double */
        case 'a':                               /* double */
        case 'A':                               /* double */
            switch (len[0]) {
            case 'L':
                (void) va_arg(ap_q, long double);           /* long double */
                break;

            case 'l':   /* does nothing */
            default:    /* no length modifier */
                (void) va_arg(ap_q, double);                /* double */
            }
            break;

        case 's':
            (void) va_arg(ap_q, char *);                    /* char * */
            break;

        case 'c':
            (void) va_arg(ap_q, int);                   /* char (promoted to int) */
            break;

        case 'p':
            (void) va_arg(ap_q, void *);                    /* void * */
            break;

        case 'n':
            (void) va_arg(ap_q, int *);                 /* int * */
            break;

        /*
         *  Custom types
         */
        case 'v':
        {
            value_box_t const *value = va_arg(ap_q, value_box_t const *);

            /*
             *  Allocations that are not part of the output
             *  string need to occur in the NULL ctx so we don't fragment
             *  any pool associated with it.
             */
            custom = value_box_asprint(NULL, value->type, value->datum.enumv, value, '"');
            if (!custom) {
                talloc_free(out);
                return NULL;
            }

        do_splice:
            /*
             *  Pass part of a format string to printf
             */
            if (fmt_q != fmt_p) {
                char *sub_fmt;

                sub_fmt = talloc_strndup(NULL, fmt_p, fmt_q - fmt_p);
                out_tmp = talloc_vasprintf_append_buffer(out, sub_fmt, ap_p);
                talloc_free(sub_fmt);
                if (!out_tmp) {
                oom:
                    fr_strerror_printf("Out of memory");
                    talloc_free(out);
                    talloc_free(custom);
                    va_end(ap_p);
                    va_end(ap_q);
                    return NULL;
                }
                out = out_tmp;

                out_tmp = talloc_strdup_append_buffer(out, custom);
                TALLOC_FREE(custom);
                if (!out_tmp) goto oom;
                out = out_tmp;

                va_end(ap_p);       /* one time use only */
                va_copy(ap_p, ap_q);    /* already advanced to the next argument */
            }

            fmt_p = p + 1;
        }
            break;

        case 'b':
        {
            uint8_t const *bin = va_arg(ap_q, uint8_t *);

            /*
             *  Only automagically figure out the length
             *  if it's not specified.
             *
             *  This allows %b to be used with stack buffers,
             *  so long as the length is specified in the format string.
             */
            if (precision == 0) precision = talloc_array_length(bin);

            custom = talloc_array(NULL, char, (precision * 2) + 1);
            if (!custom) goto oom;
            fr_bin2hex(custom, bin, precision);

            goto do_splice;
        }

        default:
            break;
        }
        fmt_q = p + 1;
    } while (++p < end);

    /*
     *  Print out the rest of the format string.
     */
    if (*fmt_p) {
        out_tmp = talloc_vasprintf_append_buffer(out, fmt_p, ap_p);
        if (!out_tmp) goto oom;
        out = out_tmp;
    }

    va_end(ap_p);
    va_end(ap_q);

    return out;
}
```

EDIT:

It's probably worth doing what the Linux folks do and overloading %p to make new format specifiers, i.e. %pA %pB.  This means the static printf format checks don't complain.