# printing typedef

Tags: c, printf, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy way to use variables of enum types as string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147267/easy-way-to-use-variables-of-enum-types-as-string-in-c)
>   [Is this possible to customize printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260170/is-this-possible-to-customize-printf)

is it possible to print own defined typedef in more convinient way?
Here is example:

```
typedef enum {
    On,
    Off,
    Unknown
} State;

State st;

st=getState();
printf("State is:%??",st);
```

I want to be displayed "State is:On | Off | Unknown"

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do a trick:

```
typedef enum {
    On = '\000 nO',
    Off = '\000ffO',
    Unknow = '\000knU'
} State;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    State st;

    st = On;

    printf("state is %s",(char *)&st);


}
```

When you specify *enum* tags you can assign an integer value.

Something like 'ABCD' is a multi-character constant that result in a 32 bit value. Each byte is the ASCII value of the corresponding character.

In the above example I assigned to each tag a multi-character constant that, treated as tring instead of integer, results in a 3 character tag.

It's rather ugly. I admit. You are forced with 3 character tags and you have to write them reversed (as on Mac OS X - Intel).

But works.

Comment: This relies on you having a little-endian processor and compiler support for multibyte 'character' literals...

Comment: If you're lucky enought to have big-endian you don't even have to write them reversed. If you're unlucky enought of not having support for multi-character constants it won't work.

Comment: Multi-character character constants are standard. However, their value is implementation-defined.