# Can I add new format specifier type to C printf in Linux platform

Tags: c

**How can I add a new format specifier say `%k` which will print a specific user-defined structure in a specific format?**

What i want to do:-

```
struct k {
    //members
}s1;
printf ("%k", s1);
```

This `printf` should print the structure in user-defined fashion.

Comment: I'd recommend against passing structures around by value like that, but otherwise it depends on your C library.  There's a great answer below for the glibc case.

Comment: @CarlNorum: There's generally no problem passing *small* structures by value. In any case, the glibc-specific solution should work for pointers to structures as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this possible to customize printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260170/is-this-possible-to-customize-printf)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible (but non-portable) using `register_printf_function`, see [12.13 Customizing printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html) from libc documentation for more details:

> The GNU C Library lets you define your own custom conversion
>   specifiers for `printf` template strings, to teach `printf` clever ways to
>   print the important data structures of your program.

[Here](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2008/12/printf-acular.html) is an example how to create such custom format specifier for MAC address.

Comment: Keep in mind that the GNU C library is separate from the GNU C compiler (gcc). There are systems (Cygwin and MinGW are examples) that use the gcc compiler with a non-glibc library.