# In C is there a way to print an array of unknown size with a single formatted print statement?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of strings and string representing the format for a printf statement. The number of strings in the array can vary, as can the format string (to match the number of strings in the array). Is there a way in C to print an array with a single format statement? I thought I'd be able to accomplish this with variadic functions, but there doesn't seem to be a way to pass an array as the args into va_list.

```
char mystring[3][20] = {"one", "two", "three"};
char format[] = "%-25s%-30s%s\n";
```

Comment: You can write your own function (more than 1 line hopefully) and call it when needed in 1 line: `int n = stringsprintf(format, mystring);`

Comment: @pmg How would you write that function?

Comment: If you don't know the outer dimension, and don't have a marker/sentinel, you can't do this in *any number* of statements.

Comment: @melpomene: [something like this](https://ideone.com/RQwbAx) but with a proper loop and proper building of the `fmt` variable :) Of course there's the limitation of string max length, but not number of strings.

Comment: @pmg You mean manually parsing the `f` string?

Comment: `f` is an unused parameter, and the function expects exactly 3 elements.

Comment: Yes, @melpomene. I'll try and write that when I get access to a real computer.

Comment: Right @WeatherVane, it's incomplete...

Comment: If you are will be intending to analyse the format string to detect the number of elements, the question says it isn't known.

Comment: I know both dimensions of the array. FWIW, I wrote a function to parse the format string and print an acceptable result, but it's ugly and doesn't accommodate a lot of variation of the print control characters.

Comment: @WeatherVane: OP said the format string matches the number of strings

Comment: Then why the rigmarole? The number of elements will be known.

Comment: @MikeBrown the question title is: "an array of unknown size". VTC as "unclear".

Comment: If you could reduce your portability requirments to GCC, then this answer might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24814570/694576

Answer (score 9):

No.͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you can get that many up-votes for just saying: "No."

Comment: @machine_1 You can if the answer is useful.