# Printing variable number of bytes using format strings with printf

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, format-string

**Goal:** Print variable number of bytes using a single format specifier.

**Environment:** x86-64 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS running in VM on an x86-64 host machine.

**Example:**

Let `%kmagic` be the format specifier I am looking for which prints `k` bytes by popping them from the stack and additing them to the output. Then, for `%rsp` pointing to a region in memory holding bytes `0xde 0xad 0xbe 0xef`, I want `printf("Next 4 bytes on the stack: %4magic")` to print `Next 4 bytes on the stack: deadbeef`.

**What I tried so far:**

1. `%khhx`, which unfortunately just results in `k-1` blank spaces followed by two hex-characters (one byte of data).
2. `%kx`, which I expected to print k/2 bytes interpreted as one number. This only prints 8 hex-characters (4 bytes) prepended by k - 8 blank spaces.

The number of non-blank characters printed matches the length of the format specifiers, i.e. the expected length of `%hhx` is 2, which is also the number of non-blank characters printed. The same holds for `%x`, which one expects to print 8 characters.

**Question:**
Is it possible to get the desired behavior? If so, how?

Comment: "Is it possible to get the desired behavior?" --> Yes.  "If so, how?'" Are you looking for someone to write this code for you?  "What I tried so far:" --> Post that code.

Comment: As state in the question, I am looking for a format specifier, not a custom printf implementation which does what I want. So no, I am not looking for someone to write code for me but instead I am looking for someone to tell me the specifier. As I am looking for the specifier and not for any code, writing the specifiers I tried should be sufficient. Posting the "code", e.g. ```printf("I want 4 bytes: %4hhx");``` just adds boilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the desired behavior? If so, how?

There does not exist `printf` format specifier to do what you want.

> Is it **possible**

Write your own `printf` implementation that supports what you want. Use [implementation-specific tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260170/is-this-possible-to-customize-printf) to create your own `printf` format specifier. You can take inspiration from [linux kernel printk `%*phN` format speciifer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to using standard `printf`. You need to write your own function and customize the `printf` function.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html

Example (simple dump):

```
int printdump (FILE *stream, const struct printf_info *info, const void *const *args)
{
    const unsigned char *ptr = *(const unsigned char **)args[0];
    size_t size = *(size_t*)args[1];
    for(size_t i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stream, "%02X%c", ptr[i-1], i % 8 ? ' ' : '\n');
    }
  return 1;
}

int printdumpargs (const struct printf_info *info, size_t n, int *argtypes)
{
  if (n == 2)
    argtypes[0] = PA_POINTER;
    argtypes[1] = PA_INT;
  return 2;
}

int main(void)
{
    double x[4] = {456543645.6786e45, 456543654, 1e345, -345.56e67};
    register_printf_function ('Y', printdump, printdumpargs);

    printf("%Y\n", &x, sizeof(x));
}
```

As I see it is depreciated now (probably no one was using it)

https://godbolt.org/z/qKs6e1d9q

Output:

```
30 18 CB 5A EF 10 13 4B
00 00 00 A6 4D 36 BB 41
00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 7F
C4 5D ED 48 9C 05 60 CE
```

Comment: `printdumpargs` seems to have an indentation issue, or possibly a missing block.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard conversion specifier for your purpose, but you can achieve your goal in C99 using an ancillary function and dynamic array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *dump_bytes(char *buf, const void *p, size_t count) {
    const unsigned char *src = p;
    char *dest = buf;
    while (count --> 0) {
        dest += sprintf(dest, "%.2X", *src++);
        if (count)
            *dest++ = ' ';
    }
    *dest = '\0';  // return an empty sting for an empty memory chunk
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    long n = 0x12345;
    printf("n is at address %p with contents: %s\n",
           (void *)&n,
           dump_bytes((char[3 * sizeof(n)]){""}, &n, sizeof(n)));
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `n is at address 0x7fff523f57d8 with contents: 45 23 01 00 00 00 00 00`

You can use a macro for simpler invocation:

```
#define DUMPBYTES(p, n)  dump_bytes((char[3 * (n)]){""}, p, n)

int main() {
    char *p = malloc(5);
    printf("allocated 5 bytes at address %p with contents: %s\n",
           p, DUMPBYTES(p, 5));
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```