# How to use C++ streams with a c_str() library API.

Tags: c++, c, printf, cout, keil

Hi here is my code snippet:

```
RIT128x96x4StringDraw(HWREGBITW(&g_ulFlags, 0) ? "1" : "0", 48, 32, 15);
```

This is only used to print some string on the screen.
I want a function or means to print numericals which can be increamented , like we do in c++

```
for(;;)
{ 
    cout<<i++;
}
```

Comment: Does your target provide the `sprintf()` function ?

Comment: NO IT DOESNOT PROVIDE THIS FUNCTION

Comment: yes i checked it has a function usprintf()

Comment: Then use usprintf to convert the number to a string, and display that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your other question [Arm Cortex Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377573/arm-cortex-m3-display), we see the prototype of the function.

```
void RIT128x96x4StringDraw(char *str, ulong x, ulong y, unsigned char level);
```

Here are the parameters,

- `x` and `y` are locations on the screen.  They are *character locations*, so this function draws text like a `printf()` or `cout`.
- The `level` parameter is an intensity; I guess you have a gray scale LCD and this is how **white** or **black** the text is.
- `str` is a *C string* that you wish to print.

Here is a sample that will print a number in a traditional *C* mode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void print_number(int i)
{
    char buffer[36];
    itoa (i,buffer,10);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw(&buffer[0], 0, 0, 15);
}
```

This uses the [`itoa()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) function to convert a number to a *C String*.  If you prefer [C++ syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c), the following code may be more preferable,

```
void print_number(int i)
{
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << i++;
  /* What ever else you wish to do... */
  RIT128x96x4StringDraw(oss.str().c_str(), 0, 0, 15);
}
```

This code is not meant to be bullet proof production code and may not even compile.  It is to demonstrate a concept.

Here is an [implementation of `itoa()`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/itoa) if your target is resource constrained.