# C++ code to R code about binary conversion

Tags: c++, r

I learned the following piece of C++ code about binary conversion and tried to translate it to R code, but not succeeded yet. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16: ++i) {
    printf("%u%u%u%u", i/8%2, i/4%2, i/2%2, i%2);  
}
```

C++ code is from below accepted answer from below post:

- [How can i generate 4 bit binary combination using recursion in C for 0,1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16150641/680068)

Comment: What code did you try in R?

Comment: Show what you tried.  While this is _technically_ C++ code, it's not really.  And it seems to be missing a newline in the output, unless that was intentional.

Comment: Check if linked post works for you.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614283/converting-decimal-to-binary-in-r

Comment: Thanks, but those posts did not provide hints to translate C++ code to R code. Fortunately, I got it working now...
for(i in 0:15) {
  print(c(floor(i/8)%%2, floor(i/4)%%2, floor(i/2)%%2, floor(i)%%2))
}