# Show two digits after decimal point in c++

Tags: c++, precision

Similar topic is already discussed in the forum. But I have some different problem in following code:

```
double total;
cin >> total;
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << total;
```

If I give input as `100.00` then program prints just `100` but not `100.00`

How can I print `100.00`?

Comment: Really? It gives 100.00 on my system (well, it gives an error for a missing semicolon, but after I fixed that it works as I expect it). Maybe you should post the ACTUAL code you have been testing this with.

Comment: are you asking for a fix to your code? or are you asking for any way to print a number with two decimals?

you should post the compiler options (or at least, the compiler) you are using to run your code, that would be very usefull to spot the problem ;)

Answer (score 86):

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << total;
```

`setprecision` specifies the *minimum* precision. So

```
cout << setprecision (2) << 1.2;
```

will print 1.2

`fixed` says that there will be a fixed number of decimal digits after the decimal point

```
cout << setprecision (2) << fixed << 1.2;
```

will print 1.20

Comment: Also, the meaning of `setprecision` depends on how the floating point output is formatted: `fixed`, `scientific` or `floatfmt()` (the default).

Comment: Is this system/implementation dependent? Many are reporting that showpoint should not be necessary... And that's the case also for my system.

Comment: @JamesKanze [`defaulfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) was added to C++11

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to print a 15 decimal number in C++ using the following:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

cout << fixed << setprecision(15) << " The Real_Pi is: " << real_pi << endl;
cout << fixed << setprecision(15) << " My Result_Pi is: " << my_pi << endl;
cout << fixed << setprecision(15) << " Processing error is: " << Error_of_Computing << endl;
cout << fixed << setprecision(15) << " Processing time is: " << End_Time-Start_Time << endl;
_getch();

return 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this, is using cstdio's printf. Actually, i'm surprised that anyone mentioned printf! anyway, you need to include the library, like this...

```
#include<cstdio>

int main() {
    double total;
    cin>>total;
    printf("%.2f\n", total);
}
```

This will print the value of "total" *(that's what `%`, and then `,total` does)* with 2 floating points *(that's what `.2f` does)*. And the `\n` at the end, is just the end of line, and this works with UVa's judge online compiler options, that is:

```
g++ -lm -lcrypt -O2 -pipe -DONLINE_JUDGE filename.cpp
```

the code you are trying to run will not run with this compiler options...

Comment: This might be useful reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c:
printf can still be used in C++, but in exceptional cases.

Comment: Lol, how is UVa judge, -lcrypt or any of the other compiler options even remotely relevant to the question?

Comment: uhh, 3 years ago answer of myself XD well, back then, when i found this question, i was getting started with competitive programming, so i thought that this "extra info" on my answer could help people that was getting started with competitive programming as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Using header file `stdio.h` you can easily do it as usual like c. before using %.2lf(set a specific number after % specifier.) using printf().

It simply printf specific digits after decimal point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   double total=100;
   printf("%.2lf",total);//this prints 100.00 like as C
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible with setiosflags(ios::showpoint).

Comment: `showpoint` should not be necessary here, since he has requested 2 digits after the decimal.  his code is correct, and should give the output he says he wants.