# I want to display 13.00 rather than 13

Tags: c#

now I have 3 textboxes that the user can type in them his degrees and the average will be calculated and displayed in another textbox! I've made the result to show just two fractional digits by calling the Math.Round() Method
This is my code:

```
double Sum = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox2.Text) + int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
double Avg =  Sum / 3;
textBox4.Text = Math.Round(Avg, 2).ToString();
```

My problem is whenever the average is equal to an integer number like 20, I want it to display 20.00

Comment: try `Avg.ToString("#.00")`

Comment: There is a wealth of information in MSDN on different string formats. Dates, times, currency, etc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a double to two decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418668/formatting-a-double-to-two-decimal-places)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280069/show-two-digits-after-decimal-point-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show two digits after decimal point in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280069/show-two-digits-after-decimal-point-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Since C# 6.0 you can use string interpolation to format variables into a string (in this case, format the number with two decimal places):

```
$"{Avg:.00}"
```

Alternatively, use `string#Format`:

```
string.Format("{0:.00}", Avg);
```

If you don't want to use either of those, you can use the `ToString` function with this parameter for that as mentioned in the comments:

```
Avg.ToString("0.00")
```