# Only two decimal places needed in to_string(price); written in c++11

Tags: c++11

I am converting `price` to a string and this needs to output two decimal places for `to_string()`. How do I do that?

```
string Antique::toString()
{
    string info = name + ": " + " $" + to_string(price); 

    return info;
}
```

Comment: Use `ostringstream` with `fixed` + `setprecision(2)`. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280069/show-two-digits-after-decimal-point-in-c)

Comment: What is the type of `price`? If it's a floating point type (`float` or `double`) expect some rounding errors.