# redirect stdout/stderr to file under unix c++ - again

Tags: c++, c, io, file-descriptor, io-redirection

**What I want to do**

redirect stdout and stderr to one or more files from inside c++

**Why I need it**

I am using an external, precompiled third-party library that produces a ridiculous amount of output, which I would like to redirect to a log file to keep the console clean.

**Conditions**

Compatibility is not a problem, the code will only run on Unix systems. The redirection should not only affect c++-style printing (`std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl`), but also c-style printing (`printf("hello world\n")`).

**What I have tried so far**

I have been browsing on stackoverflow for half a day, reading multiple answers to people having similar problems. With the help of these answers, I have been able to put together the following piece of code:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "unistd.h"

const int stdoutfd(dup(fileno(stdout)));

int redirect_stdout(const char* fname){
  fflush(stdout);
  int newstdout = open(fname, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP |     S_IROTH);
  dup2(newstdout, fileno(stdout));
  close(newstdout);
}

int restore_stdout(){
  fflush(stdout);
  dup2(stdoutfd, fileno(stdout));
  close(stdoutfd);
  return stdoutfd;
}

int main(){
  redirect_stdout("/dev/null");
  std::cout << "invisible 1" << std::endl;
  restore_stdout();
  std::cout << "visible 1" << std::endl;
  redirect_stdout("/dev/null");
  std::cout << "invisible 2" << std::endl;
  restore_stdout();
  std::cout << "visible 2" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

What I would expect to see:

```
visible 1
visible 2
```

What I actually see

```
visible 1
```

That is, when using this mechanism for the first time, it works - but if used again, restoring the output will not work.
Can somebody point out to me what I need to change in order to have the mechanism work infinitely often?

**EDIT: Why it is different from what everyone else is doing?**

Many people have similar questions (hence the "again", e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810516/c-redirecting-stdout)). However, here, I specifically target a solution that works for `C`-style and `C++`-style printing, and have a particular focus on the reusability of the functions - something that is generally not addressed in other questions and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to reuse it, don't close `stdoutfd` in `restore_stdout`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [afr0ck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2355950/afr0ck) answer of [freopen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/) I want to say that while using `freopen()` we should be careful. Once a stream like `stdout` or `stdin` is reopened with assigning the new destination(here the **'output.txt'** file) always it remains for a program unless it has been explicitly change.

```
freopen("output.txt", "a", stdout);
```

Here the standard output stream `stdout` is reopened and assigned with the **'output.txt'** file. After that whenever we use `printf()` or any other `stdout` stream like - `putchar()` then every output will goes to the **'output.txt'**. To get back the default behavior (that is printing the output in console/terminal) of `printf()` or `putchar()` we can  use the following line of code -

- for gcc, linux distribution like ubuntu - `freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);`
- for Mingw C/C++, windows - `freopen("CON", "w", stdout);`

See the code example below -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    printf("No#1. This line goes to terminal/console\n");

    freopen("output.txt", "a", stdout);
    printf("No#2. This line goes to the \"output.txt\" file\n");
    printf("No#3. This line aslo goes to the \"output.txt\" file\n");

    freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout); /*for gcc, diffrent linux distro eg. - ubuntu*/
    //freopen("CON", "w", stdout); /*Mingw C++; Windows*/
    printf("No#4. This line again goes to terminal/console\n");        

}
```

This code generate a **'output.txt'** file in your current directory and the No#2 and No#3 will be printed in the **'output.txt'** file.

Thanks

Comment: This worked for me - now I can get the output of a third-party library I'm using. The OP's code gave me seg faults. Note you can do `freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout); freopen("output.txt", "w", stderr);` and get both standard out and standard error into the same file.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this :-

```
int main()
{
    // Save original std::cin, std::cout
    std::streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::streambuf *cinbuf = std::cin.rdbuf(); 

    std::ofstream out("outfile.txt");
    std::ifstream in("infile.txt");

    //Read from infile.txt using std::cin
    std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());

    //Write to outfile.txt through std::cout 
    std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());   

    std::string test;
    std::cin >> test;           //from infile.txt
    std::cout << test << "  "; //to outfile.txt

    //Restore back.
    std::cin.rdbuf(cinbuf);   
    std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf); 

}
```

From my earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081565/c-file-redirection/18082203#18082203)

Comment: thanks for your answer - however, I should have stated that I was wanting to redirect not only c++-style print statements, but also plain-c print statements using printf - which, afaik, your solution doesn't accomplish. sorry for the imprecision, I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

well i u'd better use     freopen()

Usage Syntax:

```
freopen("RedToFile","r",stdout);
or
freopen("/dev/null","a",stdout);
```

the same goes for "stderr"

Answer (score 1):

For C++ iostreams, you can use the non-const overload of `rdbuf`
to set `std::cout` to a `std::filebuf`.  (This is best done by
means of an RAII class, since you have to restore it before
leaving main.)  For C `FILE*`, you can use `freopen`, but
I don't think you'll be able to restore it.

FWIW: both of these solutions use only standard C++ or C, so
should be portable.

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by @POW and @James Kanze 's answers and put together a little RAII class for redirecting `std::cout` to a file. It is intended to demonstrate the principle.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// RAII for redirection
class Redirect {
    public:
    
    explicit Redirect(const std::string& filenm):
        _coutbuf{ std::cout.rdbuf() },   // save original rdbuf
        _outf{ filenm }
    {
        // replace cout's rdbuf with the file's rdbuf
        std::cout.rdbuf(_outf.rdbuf());
    }
    
    ~Redirect() {
        // restore cout's rdbuf to the original
        std::cout << std::flush;
        _outf.close();    ///< not really necessary
        std::cout.rdbuf(_coutbuf); 
    }
    
    private:
    
    std::streambuf* _coutbuf;
    std::ofstream _outf;
};

// == MAIN ==

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "This message is printed to the screen" << std::endl;
    {
        // scope for the redirection
        Redirect redirect{ "output.txt" };
        std::cout << "This message goes to the file" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Printing to the screen again" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> This message is printed to the screen
>
> Printing to the screen again

Contents of the file `"output.txt"`:

> This message goes to the file