# controlling output from external libraries

Tags: c++, linux

In my process I have LOG macros, these macros output the text to std::cout and to a file. My program is linked with 3rd party libraries which output their text directly to std::cout. I have no control over the code in the external libraries and API they expose does not have an option to redirect the output to a file. Is there a way I can still control the output and redirect it to std::cout and to a file?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about shared libraries, but in principle this should work the same.  Just redirect stdout and stderr to a new stream buffer.

- [C++ file-redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081565/c-file-redirection/18082203#18082203)
- [C++: Redirecting STDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810516/c-redirecting-stdout)

Comment: This is actually not a bad idea, I will see if this is possible in my setup.

Comment: The problem is that I print to std::cout with colors which includes escaped characters so the same message is printed to file without color characters, I can not simply forward everything from std::cout to a file. But I still like your idea, I will see if I can use it some other way.

Comment: Doesn't redirecting std::cout to a file will cause my output not to be written to screen? I want the output on the screen stay the same, just be able to add logs from external libraries to my log file