# float number leading and trailing zeros format

Tags: c++

I have a float number ranging from 0.001 up to 999.999
The question: how I can format all the range numbers like this:

0.001 becomes 000.001

0.002 becomes 000.002

0.2 becomes 000.200

1.001 becoes 001.001

9.090 becomes 009.090

99.100 becomes 099.100

Thanks

Comment: Format while printing? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @AvalSarri https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144899/why-not-use-printf-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use std stream formatters from iomanip.
Stop using printf : [Why not use printf() in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144899/why-not-use-printf-in-c)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<double> values{ 0.001, 0.002, 0.2, 1.001, 9.090, 99.100 };

    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(3);
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(7);
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys , much much love and respect

Answer (score 4):

Please inspect documentation of of [stream manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip).

There couple tools which will let you do it:

```cpp
    while (std::cin >> x) {
        std::cout 
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(7) 
            << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3)
            << x << '\n';
    }
```

- `std::fixed` forces fixed format (decimal separator in same place)
- `std::setprecision(3)` defines how many digits should be after a decimal separator.
- `std::setw(7)` - defines minimum space number should occupy
- `std::setfill('0')` defines what should be used to fill extra space introduced by `std::setw(7)`.

https://godbolt.org/z/zf6q8n97r

### Extra note:

C++20 introduces nice type safe and clean equivalent of `printf` from C: [format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format_to), but there is no compiler which already supports that.

Answer (score 0):

With [`std::printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
    float f = 99.01f;
    std::printf("%07.03f", f);
}
```

`07` specifies that if the number takes up less space than 7 characters it'll be padded with leading `0`s while `03` specifies that the if the numbers after the decimal point take up less space than 3 characters then it'll be padded with trailing `0`s.

As of C++20 you can use similar formatting in `std::format`:

```
std::cout << std::format("{:07.03f}", f);
```