# C++ limit float value to the tenths place?

Tags: c++, variables, floating-point

```
float Vout, Tav, To, TempValue;

Vout = sensor.Sense();          // Sample data (read sensor)
Tav  = sensor.GetAverageTemp(); // Calculate average temperature from N samples
To   = sensor.GetLatestTemp();  // Calculate temperature from the latest sample

TempValue = sensor.GetAverageTemp();

pc.printf("Temp Value: %.1f", TempValue);//<-- Outputs Temp Value: 25.6
```

`printf` successfully outputs the value up to the tenths place.  How do I save the value up to the tenths place to the TempValue variable in C++?

I attempted to use floor():

```
TempValue = sensor.GetAverageTemp();
pc.printf("Temp Value before floor: %f\n\r", TempValue);
TempValue = floor(TempValue*100)/100;
pc.printf("Temp Value after floor: %f\n\r", TempValue);
```

That code resulted in:

> Temp Value before floor: 25.731195
>
> Temp Value after floor: 25.730000

I am almost there, however, I now have trailing zeros that I would like to remove.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: What do you mean by "save the value"?  If you want to print the value you could use the printf() function in C++ as well as C.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c

Comment: `TempValue = sensor.GetAverageTemp();` for example, has a value of: 24.822018  
  
I would like to save the value to: 24.8

Comment: So what you want to do is to perform rounding to the nearest tenth?  Take a look at the math functions at `round()`, `trunc()`, etc.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c

Answer (score 3):

You're almost certainly solving the wrong problem.

It rarely makes sense to round a floating-point value to some number of decimal places. You can do some arithmetic to take the value `24.822018` and generate a close *approximation* of `24.8`, but since floating-point is (usually) stored in binary, it can't represent `24.8` exactly. The actual stored value will likely be something like

```
24.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125
```

You already know how to *print* a floating-point value truncated to a specified number of decimal places (using `printf` with a `"%.1f"` format) -- or you can use `std::setprecision`, since you're asking about C++. (But `std::setprecision` specifies the total number of digits, not the digits after the decimal point.) In almost all cases, there's no benefit in truncating a number before you're ready to print it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `std::setprecision` from iomanip.

Sample usage would be:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << TempValue << std::endl;
```

If however, you are attempting to round a variable, something along the lines of:

```
void round_to_tenths(float &f) {
  uint32_t val = (uint32_t) f;
  float dec = f - val;
  uint32_t sd = (uint32_t)(dec * 100);
  f = val;
  uint8_t tmp;
  uint32_t test = sd % 10;
  sd /= 10;
  if (test >= 5) {
    tmp = sd % 10 + 1;
  } else {
    tmp = sd % 10;
  }
  f += (float) tmp / 10;
}
```

should work, however you still have to add checks for the negative numbers.

Comment: You beat me to the answer :-) I was able to set the precision to 24.8 by writing: `std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << TempValue << std::endl;` I changed the 2 to a 3.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question that you asked. You asked about saving the value "to the `TempValue` variable", not about printing it (which the code in your question already does). Can you update your question to make it clearer what you're actually asking?

Comment: @KeithThompson For some strange reason it 'seemed' as if it worked for limiting the numbers after the decimal.  I ended up removing all the code and just compiled:
  
`std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << TempValue << std::endl;
    
 pc.printf("Temp Value: %f", TempValue);`  
  
cout behaves just as pc.printf.  I was under the assumption cout would update the variable value. My assumption is wrong after reading about cout.  So, now I am back to my original question.  How do I limit the leading numbers after the decimal to only the tenths digit I.E. 25.9 from the original value of: 25.979151?

Comment: @dottedquad: Which goes back to my question: Why would you want to do that? You *can't* store the exact value `25.9` in a `float` object. The only context I can think of where it makes sense to do that is on output, and that's more easily done by formatting the output, not by modifying the `float` value. (And `setprecision` controls the total number of digits, not the number of digits after the decimal point.) See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28709748/827263).

Comment: @KeithThompson I now see and understand your explanation.  It is now pointless for me to do what I have been asking.  After all, all I am really trying to do is store the value of a temperature sensor and other sensors and form a JSON string and send the JSON string to a graph to plot the points.  I will now just 'edit' the float value for the purpose of visualizing the data.