# how to print a list of numbers using printf in C++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, printf, cout

I am new learning C++ and I have basic questions and basic troubles :(

I want to print a list of numbers that are coming from the next following while condition:

```
int list=0;
while (list<100){
    list=list+r;
}
```

I want to use printf instead of cout (because I still don´t know why with cout is not working).

Can anyone help me to give me the analogous printf command to

```
cout<<list<<"\t";
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Have you looked on google?

Comment: "(because I still don´t know why with cout is not working" It would be a good idea to find out.

Comment: `printf("%d\t", list);`  `printf` is less intuitive to work with than cout ; you'll be better out finding what's causing you trouble, are you using `std::cout` (std namespace) ? Are you flushing the output buffer : `std::cout<<list<<"\t" << std::endl;` ?

Comment: _"because I still don´t know why with cout is not working"_ How it doesn't work. If you elaborate about that we might be able to help you with possible fixes.

Comment: what is 'r' in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small sample program which counts up to 100 in increments of 10.

I use both `std::cout` and `printf` to display the value of `list` in each increment.

Comments added to hopefully help aid you in learning

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int r = 10;

    int list=0;
    while (list < 100)
    {
        list += r;                 // this is the same as saying list = list + r, but is more succinct

        std::cout << list << "\t"; // cout is in the std namespace, so you have to prefix with std::

        printf("%d\n", list);      // the printf format specified for int is "%d"
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 10    10
> 20    20
> 30    30
> 40    40
> 50    50
> 60    60
> 70    70
> 80    80
> 90    90
> 100   100
> ```

Please note that I didn't use `using namespace std;` at the top to import `cout` into the global namespace. IMHO this is bad practice, so I typically will prefer `std::cout` etc.

Comment: You appear not to have included _any_  header to get the declaration of printf().

Comment: @NeilButterworth it is indirectly available from `<iostream>`. [Working example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5283301de9a7221)

Comment: You must not depend on such things - the standard says that any header _may_ include another header, but it doesn't say that any header _must_ include another one. If you use a function from the Standard Library, you should always include the header that the Standard says declares it.

Comment: @SteveLorimer thanks a lot for your answer, it was really healpful. However I still have a doubt how would I change that code if what I have on the list are numbers with decimals? I tried to change the int for a double but it is not working. Any suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: @angelavtc you really should ask another question, or update your question to reflect the new requirements. SO is not a forum, but a Q&A site.
However, in this case `std::cout` will output decimal without any change. For `printf` you want to use either `%f` or `%g`. Please read more [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: @SteveLoremer got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is a C function, not a C++ one, if you are learning C++ you should try to solve the problem with `std::cout`, which is the usual way of printing.

Anyway, `printf` is pretty simple to use, it takes a first argument that is a string (a C string, so an array of char with the last char as a `'\0'` character) and as many parameters as you have format specifiers in your string (a format specifiers is a `%` char followed by another char that the function what time the variable is going to be)

Examples:

```
int intvat;
char charvar;
float floatvar;
char* stringvar; // to print it the last char of stringvar must be \0
printf("this is an int: %d", intvar);
printf("this is a char: %c", charvar);
printf("this is a string: %s", stringvar);
printf("this is a float and an int: %f, %d", floatvar, intvar);
```

For more information about printf you can refer to the reference page here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: I don't understand.  The C++ language includes `printf`, so I believe that `printf` is a C++ function.  Please cite your reference that says that `printf` is not a C++ function.

Comment: As anything that comes from the `cstdio`,  `printf` is a C function which has been included in the C++ standard libraries for compatibility (One of the main goal was that every C code should be legal C++ code, or become such with as little modifications as possible). One reference is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c , another reference is the same site in the answer, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ here it talks of all the C headers in C++, among which there is `cstdio`, where `printf` is defined

Comment: @bracco23 thanks a lot for your answer, it was really useful :)