# C++ code prints in front of cmd prompt

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I'm trying to learn how to get started learning to do C++ coding on Ubuntu.
I created a file called text.cpp with the following contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
printf("Hello World!");
}
```

I compiled it using the following line:

```
gcc test.c -o mytest
```

However, when I run ./mytest the string "Hello World!" shows up in front of the command prompt like this.

```
Hello World!mbishop@ubuntu:~bin$
```

Why is this happening and how can I get it to print after the command prompt. For example, like when you type echo "Hello Wolrd!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a missing line break.

You could use `printf` or `puts`. However, `stdio.h` is a C header, not idiomatic C++. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872576/8569012). If your aim is to code in good C++ style, the following would be more appropriate.

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What about this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238349/7692463)?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a line break after `Hello World!` like so:

```
printf("Hello World!\n");
```

**EDIT**

You could also use [`puts`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/):

```
puts("Hello World");
```

And since you ask why, it is only because printf writes output to stdout without adding a new line. If you use `puts`, it will write the output and add a newline by default. Hence, `puts()` moves the cursor to next line.

Comment: Or you know, `puts`

Comment: Yea I will update for alternative he then can choose. Thank you !