# Where does a c++ program print to?

Tags: c++

You can specify the file to which values calulcated within some program are outputed using fout, but what about when you just use, for example, printf? Does this not print something on the command line (but then this is what cout does?) It seems to me that printf does print to a file, but to what file?

Just to note that I have seen the post ['printf' vs. 'cout' in C++](http:////%20Print%20out%20the%20state%20(x,v,Energies,J)%20in%20columns%20void%20showState%20(%20particle%20&a%20,%20ostream%20&fout%20)%20%7B%20%20%20for%20(%20int%20i%20=%200%20;%20i%20%3C%20D%20;%20i++%20)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20fout%20%3C%3C%20%22%5Ct%22%3C%3Ca.x[i];%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20for%20(%20int%20i%20=%200%20;%20i%20%3C%20D%20;%20i++%20)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20fout%20%3C%3C%20%22%5Ct%22%3C%3Ca.v[i];%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20fout%20%3C%3C%20%22%5Ct%22%20%3C%3C%20a.T%20%20%20%20%20//%20KE%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%20%22%5Ct%22%20%3C%3C%20a.V%20%20%20%20%20//%20PE%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%20%22%5Ct%22%20%3C%3C%20a.T+a.V%20//%20Total%20E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%20%22%5Ct%22%20%3C%3C%20a.J%20%20%20%20%20//%20Angular%20momentum%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%20endl;%20%20%20fout%20%3C%3C%20%22#%22%20;%20%20%20for%20(%20int%20i%20=%200%20;%20i%20%3C%20D%20;%20i++%20)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20fout%20%3C%3C%20%22%5Ctx[%22%3C%3Ci%3C%3C%22]%5Ct%22;%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20for%20(%20int%20i%20=%200%20;%20i%20%3C%20D%20;%20i++%20)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20fout%20%3C%3C%20%22%5Ctv[%22%3C%3Ci%3C%3C%22]%5Ct%22;%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20fout%20%3C%3C%20%22%5CtT%5Ct%5CtV%5Ct%5CtT+V%5Ct%5CtJ%22%20;%20%20%20%20fout%20%3C%3C%20endl;%20%7D) but the answers all seem to assume knowledge of what printf fundamentally *does* which is what I am having trouble understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['printf' vs. 'cout' in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c)

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is a question about your operating system. In general, the standard output is not a physical file but a virtual file that represents a pipe, stream or device.

Comment: it prints to `stdout`, whatever that happens to be when you run the program.

Comment: *It seems to me that printf does print to a file, but to what file?* Incorrect. The `f` of `printf` stands for "formatted", not "file". `fprintf` prints to a file. `printf` prints to `stdout`, same as `std::cout`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf.

Comment: The output destination of `printf` is platform dependent.  Some embedded systems don't have output, so it doesn't go anywhere.  Some windowing frameworks don't display the output because there needs to be a text window to display to.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I disagree, it is a programming question. It's about where the output of a C++ program goes.

Comment: Have you *tried* something?

Comment: @KeithThompson I feel the answer to the question is beyond the scope of the language. It seems no different to me than if the question asked "where does user input come from?". It's given to you by the operating system. The answer to this question is entirely dependent on the operating system used and nearly language agnostic.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: it goes to *standard output*, and the C and C++ language standards have a fair amount to say about what that means.

Comment: After rereading the question, you may be confused by the assumption that `printf` and `cout` have distinct goals. They are both used to print to the standard output. `printf` is inherited by c++ from c where as `std::cout` was designed specifically for c++.

Answer (score 1):

For some output operations, you have to specify a file/stream to which the output is to be sent. The `fprintf` function (from the C library) is an example of this. Its first argument is of type `FILE*`, and it has to refer to a file that you've opened -- or to one of the default pre-opened files. The C++-specific `std::cout << "hello\n"` is another example; `std::cout` is a pre-opened output stream.

For other operations, such as `printf`, the place where the output goes is implicit. `printf(args...)` is defined to be equivalent to `fprintf(stdout, args...)`.

The C `stdout` (which is of type `FILE*`) and the C++ `std::cout` (which is of a type derived from `std::basic_ostream`) both refer to the *standard output*. That's an output stream that's opened for you by the environment as your program starts executing.

The actual location where output sent to *standard output* goes depends on the operating system and on how you invoked your program. Typically it will be printed to the current terminal window by default. (On older systems it might have been a text-only terminal screen or a hard-copy terminal.) And most operating systems provide ways to redirect standard output, such as:

```
your_program > output.txt
```

or

```
your_program | another_program
```

or

```
your_program > /dev/null
```

These (attempt to) send the output to a specified file, to the input of another program, or to a device that discards all input sent to it.

Answer (score 0):

> but what about when you just use, for example, printf?

`printf` outputs to the standard output stream.

> Does this not print something on the command line

Possibly and typically yes. The shell controls where the standard output is streamed to. Unless the output is redirected, standard output is shown on the command line.

> (but then this is what cout does?)

Yes. `std::cout` also prints to the standard output stream.

---

To understand what an input / output stream is, you can read about it from the [Single UNIX Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stdio.html). UNIX is not part of C++ standard, but the C++ standard uses the same concept of standard streams.

> A stream is associated with an external file (which may <sup>†</sup> be a physical device) ...
>
> ...
>
> At program startup, three streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly: standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output) ...

<sup>†</sup> but is not necessarily be a physical device, nor is it necessarily something that is stored on a disk.