# How do I insert a variable into a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

Requirements for a project I'm doing not only require I make a function which returns a string containing the number of a variable but also that the number of that variable is set to a number of decimal points. I have no idea how to do the former or how to do the latter outside of cout with setprecision.

Comment: Does this maybe help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c/20238349  or http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, it doesn't appear fully clear to me what your assignment actually is. But:

> I have no idea how to do the former or how to do the latter outside of cout with setprecision.

So if you know how to do it with `std::cout`, then you might use a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream out;
// now use out exactly the same way you would have used std::cout
```

Note that it's not the only way to get strings, but the one closest to what you are already familiar with...

Comment: Do I need to add a new header file for that?

Comment: @AugustA. `#include <sstream>` (see link provided).