# cout vs printf C++

Tags: c++, printf, cout

I have recently started learning C++ and I know a bit of C. I was wondering why people mostly use the `cout` statement instead of the `printf()` function in C++ (if they even do, I had just never seen use the printf function in C++). Based on my limited experience, I have found that I prefer the printf function since I find that it gives me much more control over what I'm printing out. Could someone explain the difference and which one you prefer?

Comment: You can overload `operator<<` to support your own class with `cout` (and other `std::ostream` classes) - you don't have any such option for `printf`

Comment: `printf` is not type-safe. This is why most people prefer `cout`.

Comment: "From my limited experience, I have found that I prefer the printf function since I find that it gives me much more control over what I'm printing out." - As you said yourself this is only based on your limited experience. I don't see why C++ I/O streams give less control than C I/O functions.

Comment: Consider using [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev/latest/) instead of the unsafe functions defined in `<cstdio>`. Also note that you can control input/output streams with [manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: I would doubt the premise that "people mostly use cout". In beginner tutorials with console input and output, perhaps yes, but that's mostly because they do not bother with the dirty details of error handling and stream status. Lat not least `<iostream>` is huge and leads to long compile times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cout` is the C++ version of `printf`. `printf` requires you to specify the type, `cout` does not. `printf` is generally faster as well. So `cout` is not so fast but easy, and `printf` is fast, but not way to easy if you are not familiar with it. When using c++, `cout` should be used, unless you need `printf`. I prefer `cout` because it is type-safe (big thing!), and it is more c++ish (if that makes sense).

**Notes:**

- `printf` is in stdio
- `printf` came from `c`
- `printf` is not type safe!

Answer (score 1):

This answer ['printf' vs. 'cout' in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c) explains well the differences between `std::cout` and `printf`. Both have their own advantages and shortcomings.

`iostreams` offers additional features such as type safety and extensibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to add specific parameters

```
printf ("Characters: %c %c", 'a', 65);
```

%c - char ,
%d - integer,
%f - float

You need to add for example %d to declare that variable type is integer

In cout you don't need to do this, you can even add strings or more variables

```
cout << "Hello\n";
int a = 7;
cout << "Number seven is : " << a;
```

This one will print

```
Hello
Number seven is : 7
```

I think that most of programmers prefers cout

Comment: Your second example should be `cout << "Number seven is : " << a;`

Comment: I find that the parameters give me a higher level of control, which is (in my opinion) the purpose of a low-level programming language. To me, it seems like cout belongs in  a language like Python or javascript instead of C++

Comment: @UnholySheep That's right. I'm sorry I currently started programming in Java so I made a big mistake. I edited my answer.