# What are the differences between libfmt and std::format?

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

I am aware that the c++20 format proposal is a formalization of *parts* of libfmt, and that libfmt is a compliant implementation of that formalization. However, it's my understanding that libfmt provides additional functionality beyond that specified in the c++20 standard. What are the additional features?

Additional, are the major compiler vendors simply including a subset of libfmt or reimplementing it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are a bunch of things in libfmt that are not in C++20 format:

- `fmt::print()` to print directly to stdout.
- `fmt::memory_buffer` as basically a dynamically sized container that you could format into via `fmt::format_to(buf, ...)`.
- Support for formatting [ranges and tuples](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#ranges-api), including `fmt::join()`.
- Support for [named arguments](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#literal-based-api) like `fmt::print("Elapsed time: {s:.2f} seconds", "s"_a=1.23);`
- Compile-time format strings via [`FMT_COMPILE`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#format-string-compilation), although both `fmt::format` and C++20's `std::format` do compile-time format string parsing by default. `fmt::format` has an escape hook for this named `fmt::runtime`, `std::format` has no such hook.

---

C++23 update: `std::print` ([P2093](https://wg21.link/p2093)) and formatting ranges and tuples ([P2286](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2286r8.html)) are in C++23.

Comment: I don't think [`fmt::color` and `fmt::emphasis`](https://godbolt.org/z/d9xxT6) is in C++20 either, but I'd love to be wrong. :-)

Comment: Does C++20 allow compile-time `string_view` literals as a substitute for `FMT_COMPILE`?

Comment: Or put another way, could C++20 implementations perform the same sort of optimizations as `FMT_COMPILE` when a `string_view` literal is passed as the format string?