# Equivalent statement of printf("%d\n", x > y ? x : y); in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

What is the equivalent statement of this commented line in C++ :

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    // equivalent of this line in c++ : printf("%d\n", x > y ? x : y); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C functions still work in C++, do you really need a replacement?

Comment: `std::cout << (x > y ? x : y) << "\n";`

Comment: Is there a reason the C-style function doesn't work for you?

Comment: Have a look at std::string, std::cout and std::format (C++20). 
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/output-with-ostream-and-ios/, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format

Comment: It works but I just wanted to write the code differently because I'm beginner to c++ and don't know much about it.

Comment: It is a good question, printf has its issues.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c

Comment: Depends on what you mean by equivalent.   Assuming there is an `#include <cstdio>` (or `#include <stdio.h>`) and a `using namespace std` directive in effect (which is one option to use `cin` without fully qualifying as `std::cin`), the code will compile and work the same way "as is" in C++.   If you want the same output to standard output, but using `std::cout` instead of calling `printf()`, `std::cout << (x > y> ? x : y) << '\n'` will produce the same effect.   You can also avoid doing `x > y ? x : y` by adding `#include <algorithm>` and using `std:max(x,y)` instead.

Comment: `std::cout << std::max(x, y) << '\n';` would be a more C++-ish way to do it.

Comment: @NazmusSakibSibly then please [read a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714) because SO isn't a place for learning and you'll quickly be turned down by that

Answer (score 1):

You could use std::format, which is very similar to the printf function but it only appeared in C++20.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    std::cout << std::format("{0}", x > y ? x : y) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```