# Why is my Java program running faster than my C++ program , both doing the same thing

Tags: java, c++, performance, c++11, g++

I wrote a program in both C++ and Java to print "Hello World" 100,000 times, but I noticed that the C++ code takes too long compared to the Java code;
The Java code takes about 6 seconds averagely and the C++ code takes about 18 seconds averagely, both run from the command line;
Can someone please explain why, thanks.

The name of the program is first.java and first.cpp for Java and C++ respectively
I used:  `java first.java`; and  `first.exe`; both from the command line

g++ --version
g++ (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0

java --version
java 13.0.2, 2020-01-14

Java Code

```
class first {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long dur = end - start;
        System.out.println(dur / 1000);
    }

}
```

C++ Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    cout << elapsed_seconds.count() << endl;
}
```

Comment: The two programs are *not* doing the same thing. If you want them to be closer equivalents, add a call to `System.out.flush();` to the loop in your Java code.

Comment: You may also be interested by [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio#:~:text=If%20the%20synchronization%20is%20turned%20off%2C%20the%20C%2B%2B%20standard%20streams%20are%20allowed%20to%20buffer%20their%20I/O%20independently%2C%20which%20may%20be%20considerably%20faster%20in%20some%20cases.) which could significantly increase the speed of IO operations.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  IIRC, `System.out` is line-buffered by default, so `System.out.println()` will flush the buffer on every call.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number please how would I do that, thanks

Comment: @Peter Yeah that's true. Still, there's an extra function call in the C++ code which is absent in the Java code. Admittedly with IO bound code this should be completely negligible but if OP *does* see a difference it must come from *somewhere* (well, C++ IO also does some additional unnecessary things to sync with C IO).

Comment: Replacing `endl` with `\n` may increase the performance because `endl` flushes the buffer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['printf' vs. 'cout' in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c)

Comment: @ArmanOganesyan Already discussed in the comments above.

Comment: @Fareanor waw, I tried it( std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false) ), and it's working, thanks; can you explain why it's improved; from the docs, does the synchronization means that the c++ out stream calls the c out stream? thus bringing an overhead? ...the code now runs in 7 Sec

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah, it seems there are some syncing causing the slowdown

Comment: @Atolz You should read the [given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74715010/11455384), it's pretty good and clear :)

Comment: @ArmanOganesyan waw, thanks, using ```\n``` instead of ```endl``` improved it further, now at 1.5 sec.....what an improvement;  turning off synchronization and substituting with ```\n``` did it, thanks you all

Comment: @Atolz -- it's unfortunate that `std::endl` has become the default line-ending for many programmers. It's almost never appropriate. As you've seen, `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 6):

There are several relevant differences between your C++ and Java code:

1. By default C++ IO streams synchronise their state with the underlying C streams. This takes time. To avoid this (which you can do *only* if you know that your code does not mix C and C++ IO operations!), add the following to the beginning of your `main` code:

   ```cpp
   std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
   ```
2. `cout << endl;` is equivalent to `cout << "\n" << flush;` (which, in turn, is equivalent to `cout << "\n"; cout.flush();`). The `flush` call is absent from your Java code. You could add it to your Java code or, better, remove it from your C++ code: you almost never need to use `endl`/`flush`. Instead, just use

   ```cpp
   cout << "Hello World\n";
   ```

   As noted by Peter in the comments, most systems flush the stdout stream on newline anyway (at least when attached to a terminal) so one might expect this not to make a difference. However, it does make a (substantial!) difference e.g. when piping the output to a file.
3. Your Java benchmark code truncates fractional seconds. To show those fractions of seconds (relevant since the code runs in <1s!), change the relevant line to

   ```java
   System.out.println(dur / 1000.0);
   ```
4. Be sure to compile your C++ code with optimisations enabled; with GCC/clang/ICC, you do this by passing `-O2`. MSVC has a similar flag, `/O2` (there are higher optimisation levels but they have particular issues; `-O2` is pretty much the default setting people use).
5. Conversely, `java first.java` will first *compile* the code *every time* you invoke it. To make the comparison fair, be sure to run `javac first.java` ahead of time, and then execute the code via `java first`.

Making these changes causes the C++ code to overtake the Java code on my system. This is most noticeable when increasing the loop size from 100,000 to 1,000,000: the C++ code now runs in milliseconds, while the Java code takes several seconds (be sure to pipe the output to a file! Otherwise you will be purely measuring the latency/rendering speed of your terminal, not the performance of the code).

Comment: If you want to show off the capabilities of an ahead-of-time compiler, `-O3 -march=native` will auto-vectorize loops where that looks useful, and use ISA extensions supported by your CPU.  Of course this code probably only needs `-O1` since it spends all its time calling a library function, `iostream::operator<<(const char*)`; a tight loop around that is trivial for a compiler to optimize well enough.  But yeah, `-O2` is a reasonable minimum for benchmarking, and somewhat realistic since a lot of code does get built with that option and without any `-march` beyond baseline x86-64 or AArch64.