# How to resolve Fatal error: 'print' file not found?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++23

So, I was trying to use the C++23 `std::print` and `std::println` functions, but when I tried to compile the following code using the `-std=c++2b` flag, it gave a `fatal error: 'print' file not found #include <print>`. I tried including everything from `<iostream>` to `<cstdio>`, but it still didn't compile. Does anyone know how to resolve this? I'm on MacOS and I've just updated my Command Line Developer Tools to the latest version – twice even!

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
#include <print>

int main() {
    std::print("Hello everyone!\n");
    std::println("Hello again!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler support for `<print>` is very poor at the moment. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c/77617851#77617851) for an altenative.

Comment: So Apple clang doesn't have a `<print>` header yet. Documented here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/23

Comment: You could install **llvm** (`brew install llvm`, 17.0.6) or **GCC** (`brew install gcc`, 13.2.0) to see if either one of them have the C++23 `print` feature.  (There's probably a way to check before installing them, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to do that.)  You could use the C++ `__cpp_lib_print` feature flag to check for the feature.

Comment: I ran into this same issue when trying C++23 on linux. I had to use the `-stdlib=libc++` and for some reason had to specify `include_directories()` for the headers. Not sure if it's related or not.